# How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview, android-filterable

I am trying to implement the `SearchView` from the support library. I want the user to be to use the `SearchView` to filter a `List` of movies in a `RecyclerView`.

I have followed a few tutorials so far and I have added the `SearchView` to the `ActionBar`, but I am not really sure where to go from here. I have seen a few examples but none of them show results as you start typing.

This is my `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new CardAdapter() {
            @Override
            public Filter getFilter() {
                return null;
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And this is my `Adapter`:

```
public abstract class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<Movie> mItems;

    public CardAdapter() {
        super();
        mItems = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Spiderman");
        movie.setRating("92");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Doom 3");
        movie.setRating("91");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Transformers");
        movie.setRating("88");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Transformers 2");
        movie.setRating("87");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Transformers 3");
        movie.setRating("86");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Noah");
        movie.setRating("86");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Ironman");
        movie.setRating("86");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Ironman 2");
        movie.setRating("86");
        mItems.add(movie);

        movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Ironman 3");
        movie.setRating("86");
        mItems.add(movie);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        Movie movie = mItems.get(i);
        viewHolder.tvMovie.setText(movie.getName());
        viewHolder.tvMovieRating.setText(movie.getRating());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView tvMovie;
        public TextView tvMovieRating;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvMovie = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieName);
            tvMovieRating = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieRating);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1018, accepted):

## Introduction

Since it is not really clear from your question what exactly you are having trouble with, I wrote up this quick walkthrough about how to implement this feature; if you still have questions feel free to ask.

I have a working example of everything I am talking about here in this [**GitHub Repository**](https://github.com/xaverkapeller/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo).

In any case the result should looks something like this:

[image: demo image]

If you first want to play around with the demo app you can install it from the Play Store:

[image: Get it on Google Play]

Anyway lets get started.

---

## Setting up the `SearchView`

In the folder `res/menu` create a new file called `main_menu.xml`. In it add an item and set the `actionViewClass` to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`. Since you are using the support library you have to use the namespace of the support library to set the `actionViewClass` attribute. Your xml file should look something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
          app:showAsAction="always"/>
      
</menu>
```

In your `Fragment` or `Activity` you have to inflate this menu xml like usual, then you can look for the `MenuItem` which contains the `SearchView` and implement the `OnQueryTextListener` which we are going to use to listen for changes to the text entered into the `SearchView`:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    // Here is where we are going to implement the filter logic
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
```

And now the `SearchView` is ready to be used. We will implement the filter logic later on in `onQueryTextChange()` once we are finished implementing the `Adapter`.

---

## Setting up the `Adapter`

First and foremost this is the model class I am going to use for this example:

```
public class ExampleModel {

    private final long mId;
    private final String mText;

    public ExampleModel(long id, String text) {
        mId = id;
        mText = text;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

It's just your basic model which will display a text in the `RecyclerView`. This is the layout I am going to use to display the text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.github.wrdlbrnft.searchablerecyclerviewdemo.ui.models.ExampleModel"/>

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:text="@{model.text}"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

As you can see I use Data Binding. If you have never worked with data binding before don't be discouraged! It's very simple and powerful, however I can't explain how it works in the scope of this answer.

This is the `ViewHolder` for the `ExampleModel` class:

```
public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final ItemExampleBinding mBinding;

    public ExampleViewHolder(ItemExampleBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        mBinding = binding;
    }

    public void bind(ExampleModel item) {
        mBinding.setModel(item);
    }
}
```

Again nothing special. It just uses data binding to bind the model class to this layout as we have defined in the layout xml above.

Now we can finally come to the really interesting part: Writing the Adapter. I am going to skip over the basic implementation of the `Adapter` and am instead going to concentrate on the parts which are relevant for this answer.

But first there is one thing we have to talk about: The [**`SortedList`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html) class.

---

## SortedList

The `SortedList` is a completely amazing tool which is part of the `RecyclerView` library. It takes care of notifying the `Adapter` about changes to the data set and does so it a very efficient way. The only thing it requires you to do is specify an order of the elements. You need to do that by implementing a `compare()` method which compares two elements in the `SortedList` just like a `Comparator`. But instead of sorting a `List` it is used to sort the items in the `RecyclerView`!

The `SortedList` interacts with the `Adapter` through a `Callback` class which you have to implement:

```
private final SortedList.Callback<ExampleModel> mCallback = new SortedList.Callback<ExampleModel>() {

    @Override
    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
         mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ExampleModel a, ExampleModel b) {
        return mComparator.compare(a, b);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(ExampleModel oldItem, ExampleModel newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(ExampleModel item1, ExampleModel item2) {
        return item1.getId() == item2.getId();
    }
}
```

In the methods at the top of the callback like `onMoved`, `onInserted`, etc. you have to call the equivalent notify method of your `Adapter`. The three methods at the bottom `compare`, `areContentsTheSame` and `areItemsTheSame` you have to implement according to what kind of objects you want to display and in what order these objects should appear on the screen.

Let's go through these methods one by one:

```
@Override
public int compare(ExampleModel a, ExampleModel b) {
    return mComparator.compare(a, b);
}
```

This is the `compare()` method I talked about earlier. In this example I am just passing the call to a `Comparator` which compares the two models. If you want the items to appear in alphabetical order on the screen. This comparator might look like this:

```
private static final Comparator<ExampleModel> ALPHABETICAL_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<ExampleModel>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ExampleModel a, ExampleModel b) {
        return a.getText().compareTo(b.getText());
    }
};
```

Now let's take a look at the next method:

```
@Override
public boolean areContentsTheSame(ExampleModel oldItem, ExampleModel newItem) {
    return oldItem.equals(newItem);
}
```

The purpose of this method is to determine if the content of a model has changed. The `SortedList` uses this to determine if a change event needs to be invoked - in other words if the `RecyclerView` should crossfade the old and new version. If you model classes have a correct `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation you can usually just implement it like above. If we add an `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation to the `ExampleModel` class it should look something like this:

```
public class ExampleModel implements SortedListAdapter.ViewModel {

    private final long mId;
    private final String mText;

    public ExampleModel(long id, String text) {
        mId = id;
        mText = text;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        ExampleModel model = (ExampleModel) o;

        if (mId != model.mId) return false;
        return mText != null ? mText.equals(model.mText) : model.mText == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = (int) (mId ^ (mId >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (mText != null ? mText.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Quick side note: Most IDE's like Android Studio, IntelliJ and Eclipse have functionality to generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations for you at the press of a button! So you don't have to implement them yourself. Look up on the internet how it works in your IDE!

Now let's take a look at the last method:

```
@Override
public boolean areItemsTheSame(ExampleModel item1, ExampleModel item2) {
    return item1.getId() == item2.getId();
}
```

The `SortedList` uses this method to check if two items refer to the same thing. In simplest terms (without explaining how the `SortedList` works) this is used to determine if an object is already contained in the `List` and if either an add, move or change animation needs to be played. If your models have an id you would usually compare just the id in this method. If they don't you need to figure out some other way to check this, but however you end up implementing this depends on your specific app. Usually it is the simplest option to give all models an id - that could for example be the primary key field if you are querying the data from a database.

With the `SortedList.Callback` correctly implemented we can create an instance of the `SortedList`:

```
final SortedList<ExampleModel> list = new SortedList<>(ExampleModel.class, mCallback);
```

As the first parameter in the constructor of the `SortedList` you need to pass the class of your models. The other parameter is just the `SortedList.Callback` we defined above.

Now let's get down to business: If we implement the `Adapter` with a `SortedList` it should look something like this:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleViewHolder> {

    private final SortedList<ExampleModel> mSortedList = new SortedList<>(ExampleModel.class, new SortedList.Callback<ExampleModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ExampleModel a, ExampleModel b) {
            return mComparator.compare(a, b);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(ExampleModel oldItem, ExampleModel newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(ExampleModel item1, ExampleModel item2) {
            return item1.getId() == item2.getId();
        }
    });

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final Comparator<ExampleModel> mComparator;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, Comparator<ExampleModel> comparator) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mComparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final ItemExampleBinding binding = ItemExampleBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ExampleModel model = mSortedList.get(position);
        holder.bind(model);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSortedList.size();
    }
}
```

The `Comparator` used to sort the item is passed in through the constructor so we can use the same `Adapter` even if the items are supposed to be displayed in a different order.

Now we are almost done! But we first need a way to add or remove items to the `Adapter`. For this purpose we can add methods to the `Adapter` which allow us to add and remove items to the `SortedList`:

```
public void add(ExampleModel model) {
    mSortedList.add(model);
}

public void remove(ExampleModel model) {
    mSortedList.remove(model);
}

public void add(List<ExampleModel> models) {
    mSortedList.addAll(models);
}

public void remove(List<ExampleModel> models) {
    mSortedList.beginBatchedUpdates();
    for (ExampleModel model : models) {
        mSortedList.remove(model);
    }
    mSortedList.endBatchedUpdates();
}
```

We don't need to call any notify methods here because the `SortedList` already does this for through the `SortedList.Callback`! Aside from that the implementation of these methods is pretty straight forward with one exception: the remove method which removes a `List` of models. Since the `SortedList` has only one remove method which can remove a single object we need to loop over the list and remove the models one by one. Calling `beginBatchedUpdates()` at the beginning batches all the changes we are going to make to the `SortedList` together and improves performance. When we call `endBatchedUpdates()` the `RecyclerView` is notified about all the changes at once.

Additionally what you have to understand is that if you add an object to the `SortedList` and it is already in the `SortedList` it won't be added again. Instead the `SortedList` uses the `areContentsTheSame()` method to figure out if the object has changed - and if it has the item in the `RecyclerView` will be updated.

Anyway, what I usually prefer is one method which allows me to replace all items in the `RecyclerView` at once. Remove everything which is not in the `List` and add all items which are missing from the `SortedList`:

```
public void replaceAll(List<ExampleModel> models) {
    mSortedList.beginBatchedUpdates();
    for (int i = mSortedList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final ExampleModel model = mSortedList.get(i);
        if (!models.contains(model)) {
            mSortedList.remove(model);
        }
    }
    mSortedList.addAll(models);
    mSortedList.endBatchedUpdates();
}
```

This method again batches all updates together to increase performance. The first loop is in reverse since removing an item at the start would mess up the indexes of all items that come up after it and this can lead in some instances to problems like data inconsistencies. After that we just add the `List` to the `SortedList` using `addAll()` to add all items which are not already in the `SortedList` and - just like I described above - update all items that are already in the `SortedList` but have changed.

And with that the `Adapter` is complete. The whole thing should look something like this:

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleViewHolder> {

    private final SortedList<ExampleModel> mSortedList = new SortedList<>(ExampleModel.class, new SortedList.Callback<ExampleModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ExampleModel a, ExampleModel b) {
            return mComparator.compare(a, b);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(ExampleModel oldItem, ExampleModel newItem) {
            return oldItem.equals(newItem);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(ExampleModel item1, ExampleModel item2) {
            return item1 == item2;
        }
    });

    private final Comparator<ExampleModel> mComparator;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, Comparator<ExampleModel> comparator) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mComparator = comparator;
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final ItemExampleBinding binding = ItemExampleBinding.inflate(mInflater, parent, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ExampleModel model = mSortedList.get(position);
        holder.bind(model);
    }

    public void add(ExampleModel model) {
        mSortedList.add(model);
    }

    public void remove(ExampleModel model) {
        mSortedList.remove(model);
    }

    public void add(List<ExampleModel> models) {
        mSortedList.addAll(models);
    }

    public void remove(List<ExampleModel> models) {
        mSortedList.beginBatchedUpdates();
        for (ExampleModel model : models) {
            mSortedList.remove(model);
        }
        mSortedList.endBatchedUpdates();
    }

    public void replaceAll(List<ExampleModel> models) {
        mSortedList.beginBatchedUpdates();
        for (int i = mSortedList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final ExampleModel model = mSortedList.get(i);
            if (!models.contains(model)) {
                mSortedList.remove(model);
            }
        }
        mSortedList.addAll(models);
        mSortedList.endBatchedUpdates();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSortedList.size();
    }
}
```

The only thing missing now is to implement the filtering!

---

## Implementing the filter logic

To implement the filter logic we first have to define a `List` of all possible models. For this example I create a `List` of `ExampleModel` instances from an array of movies:

```
private static final String[] MOVIES = new String[]{
        ...
};

private static final Comparator<ExampleModel> ALPHABETICAL_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<ExampleModel>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ExampleModel a, ExampleModel b) {
        return a.getText().compareTo(b.getText());
    }
};

private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
private List<ExampleModel> mModels;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(this, ALPHABETICAL_COMPARATOR);

    mBinding.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mBinding.recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mModels = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String movie : MOVIES) {
        mModels.add(new ExampleModel(movie));
    }
    mAdapter.add(mModels);
}
```

Nothing special going on here, we just instantiate the `Adapter` and set it to the `RecyclerView`. After that we create a `List` of models from the movie names in the `MOVIES` array. Then we add all the models to the `SortedList`.

Now we can go back to `onQueryTextChange()` which we defined earlier and start implementing the filter logic:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    final List<ExampleModel> filteredModelList = filter(mModels, query);
    mAdapter.replaceAll(filteredModelList);
    mBinding.recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    return true;
}
```

This is again pretty straight forward. We call the method `filter()` and pass in the `List` of `ExampleModel`s as well as the query string. We then call `replaceAll()` on the `Adapter` and pass in the filtered `List` returned by `filter()`. We also have to call `scrollToPosition(0)` on the `RecyclerView` to ensure that the user can always see all items when searching for something. Otherwise the `RecyclerView` might stay in a scrolled down position while filtering and subsequently hide a few items. Scrolling to the top ensures a better user experience while searching.

The only thing left to do now is to implement `filter()` itself:

```
private static List<ExampleModel> filter(List<ExampleModel> models, String query) {
    final String lowerCaseQuery = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<ExampleModel> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ExampleModel model : models) {
        final String text = model.getText().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(lowerCaseQuery)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

The first thing we do here is call `toLowerCase()` on the query string. We don't want our search function to be case sensitive and by calling `toLowerCase()` on all strings we compare we can ensure that we return the same results regardless of case. It then just iterates through all the models in the `List` we passed into it and checks if the query string is contained in the text of the model. If it is then the model is added to the filtered `List`.

And that's it! The above code will run on API level 7 and above and starting with API level 11 you get item animations for free!

I realize that this is a very detailed description which probably makes this whole thing seem more complicated than it really is, but there is a way we can generalize this whole problem and make implementing an `Adapter` based on a `SortedList` much simpler.

---

## Generalizing the problem and simplifying the Adapter

In this section I am not going to go into much detail - partly because I am running up against the character limit for answers on Stack Overflow but also because most of it already explained above - but to summarize the changes: We can implemented a base `Adapter` class which already takes care of dealing with the `SortedList` as well as binding models to `ViewHolder` instances and provides a convenient way to implement an `Adapter` based on a `SortedList`. For that we have to do two things:

- We need to create a `ViewModel` interface which all model classes have to implement
- We need to create a `ViewHolder` subclass which defines a `bind()` method the `Adapter` can use to bind models automatically.

This allows us to just focus on the content which is supposed to be displayed in the `RecyclerView` by just implementing the models and there corresponding `ViewHolder` implementations. Using this base class we don't have to worry about the intricate details of the `Adapter` and its `SortedList`.

#### SortedListAdapter

Because of the character limit for answers on StackOverflow I can't go through each step of implementing this base class or even add the full source code here, but you can find the full source code of this base class - I called it `SortedListAdapter` - in this [**GitHub Gist**](https://gist.github.com/xaverkapeller/1b6233e99c6b7d54c204e61c1c9c0bf3).

To make your life simple I have published a library on jCenter which contains the `SortedListAdapter`! If you want to use it then all you need to do is add this dependency to your app's build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.github.wrdlbrnft:sorted-list-adapter:0.2.0.1'
```

You can find more information about this library [**on the library homepage**](https://xaverkapeller.github.io/SortedListAdapter/).

#### Using the SortedListAdapter

To use the `SortedListAdapter` we have to make two changes:

- Change the `ViewHolder` so that it extends `SortedListAdapter.ViewHolder`. The type parameter should be the model which should be bound to this `ViewHolder` - in this case `ExampleModel`. You have to bind data to your models in `performBind()` instead of `bind()`.

  ```
   public class ExampleViewHolder extends SortedListAdapter.ViewHolder<ExampleModel> {

       private final ItemExampleBinding mBinding;

       public ExampleViewHolder(ItemExampleBinding binding) {
           super(binding.getRoot());
           mBinding = binding;
       }

       @Override
       protected void performBind(ExampleModel item) {
           mBinding.setModel(item);
       }
   }
  ```
- Make sure that all your models implement the `ViewModel` interface:

  ```
   public class ExampleModel implements SortedListAdapter.ViewModel {
       ...
   }
  ```

After that we just have to update the `ExampleAdapter` to extend `SortedListAdapter` and remove everything we don't need anymore. The type parameter should be the type of model you are working with - in this case `ExampleModel`. But if you are working with different types of models then set the type parameter to `ViewModel`.

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends SortedListAdapter<ExampleModel> {

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, Comparator<ExampleModel> comparator) {
        super(context, ExampleModel.class, comparator);
    }

    @Override
    protected ViewHolder<? extends ExampleModel> onCreateViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final ItemExampleBinding binding = ItemExampleBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean areItemsTheSame(ExampleModel item1, ExampleModel item2) {
        return item1.getId() == item2.getId();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean areItemContentsTheSame(ExampleModel oldItem, ExampleModel newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }
}
```

After that we are done! However one last thing to mention: The `SortedListAdapter` does not have the same `add()`, `remove()` or `replaceAll()` methods our original `ExampleAdapter` had. It uses a separate `Editor` object to modify the items in the list which can be accessed through the `edit()` method. So if you want to remove or add items you have to call `edit()` then add and remove the items on this `Editor` instance and once you are done, call `commit()` on it to apply the changes to the `SortedList`:

```
mAdapter.edit()
        .remove(modelToRemove)
        .add(listOfModelsToAdd)
        .commit();
```

All changes you make this way are batched together to increase performance. The `replaceAll()` method we implemented in the chapters above is also present on this `Editor` object:

```
mAdapter.edit()
        .replaceAll(mModels)
        .commit();
```

If you forget to call `commit()` then none of your changes will be applied!

Comment: i am not an expert where can i find the ItemExampleBinding ? the import is not working

Comment: Are you talking about the example project in the Github Repository? It uses data binding. The Binding classes are generated from the layout xml files by the Android Gradle Plugin when you compile the project.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with data binding check out this offical guide from the Android Developer page: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot :D, yep this is my first time working with data binding i didn't knew that the databinding was generated automatically i compiled my project and everything is working, at my first try, this feels weird, i usually get exceptions when I dive into unknown territory

Comment: @TiagoOliveira Well it's made to just work out of the box :D Data binding is hurdle for people unfamiliar with it, but I included it anyway because it's amazing and I want to promote it. For some reason not many people seem to know about it...

Comment: I haven't yet read the whole answer, I had to pause my reading somewhere at half to write this comment - this is one of the best answers I have find here on the SO! Thanks!

Comment: Do we have to do filtering in background thread because of performance?

Comment: @mladj0ni If you are filtering a large dataset or retrieving results from a database or a web service or anything else that might take a while then you should do it in a separate thread and then post the results on the main thread once everything is done.

Comment: I just love how you're like: "It's not clear from your question what you're having trouble with, so here's a full fledged example I just did" :D

Comment: +1 just to show us that Data Binding exists in Android! I've never hear about that and seems that I'll begin using it. Thanks

Comment: What is ItemExampleBinding class? can you please share its implementation.

Comment: @TusharThakur There is no implementation. It is a class auto generated by the Android Data Binding library. Here you can find more information about the Data Binding Library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: To have `AndroidStudio` generate `equals()` and `hashCode()`: Select from the toolbar `Code` -> `Generate...` -> select `equals() and hashCode()` and then choose wisely which fields are allowed to be `null`.

Comment: TL;DR - Made everything by myself without such difficult explanation. App is nice.

Comment: What a great answer! Also thanks for letting me know Android support data binding. I didn't know. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! To generate the equals() and haschCode() functions in Android Studio - Ctrl+Shit+O - a window pops up with all the functions you can override.

Comment: How would you use this to compare multiple things of your model? For example, you're now comparing the text (the movie title) but what if you also want to search by the director? So your model would have a director field and you'd set up another comparator which you'd send to your adapter, but then? Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37207601/956975 - you just add a FILTER not another comparator.

Comment: When I use `.edit().replaceAll().commit()`, it doesn't remove values in the adapter, `itemsToRemove` size is 0, why is that?

Comment: Nevermind, tried using `.replaceAll()` in the very first part of initialization where I add initial list, it works as intended now

Comment: Of course I am glad somebody puts so much effort on a answer, but I would prefer that questions don't need such a long/complex solution.

Comment: @David Well that's relative. I could tell you about a much simpler way to achieve something similar, but the results would by far not be as good. Good solutions usually take more work. However I have made a library that takes care of most of this for you. I link to it at the bottom of the answer as an option for people who don't want to implement all this themselves - it also has a few additional features and performance optimizations. You can check it out here: https://wrdlbrnft.github.io/SortedListAdapter/

Comment: what if each row is a gridView? Keep getting indexOutofBounds

Comment: I am using your method `replaceAll` and it messes up with indexes. I had to use `public void replaceAll(List<ExampleModel> models) {
    mSortedList.beginBatchedUpdates();
    mSortedList.clear();
    mSortedList.addAll(models);
    mSortedList.endBatchedUpdates();
}`

Comment: Starting with the Support Library version 27.1.0, the `SortedList` class has a `replaceAll(@NonNull T... items)` method. There is also a new `ListAdapter` class that extends the regular `RecyclerView.Adapter` class, which was designed specifically for updating the contents of the `RecyclerView` asynchronously: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter.html

Comment: This solution is ridiculously long and generally speaking over-engineered. 
Go for the second one.

Comment: You forgot ; at the end of mCallback

Comment: what about when your menu is in your activity yet your list and adapter connection is in a separate fragment?

Comment: Could have been made much much simpler.. too complicated I would say.

Comment: This answer is amazing. Glad you use databinding. All other answers related to recyclerview just use findViewById and code-behind on the fragment/activity.

Comment: @EnricoCasini the problems of others solutions reside in the call `notifyDataSetChanged()` with Lack of the logic to notify items changed and removed that is a problem. This solution is complete, good well and clear implemented.

Answer (score 242):

All you need to do is to add `filter` method in `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
public void filter(String text) {
    items.clear();
    if(text.isEmpty()){
        items.addAll(itemsCopy);
    } else{
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        for(PhoneBookItem item: itemsCopy){
            if(item.name.toLowerCase().contains(text) || item.phone.toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                items.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`itemsCopy` is initialized in adapter's constructor like `itemsCopy.addAll(items)`.

If you do so, just call `filter` from `OnQueryTextListener`:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        adapter.filter(query);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.filter(newText);
        return true;
    }
});
```

It's an example from filtering my phonebook by name and phone number.

Comment: RecyclerView.Adapter  mAdapter = new ProjectListAdapter(getDataSet()); i am using adapter in this way.. how i will add filter method into it?

Comment: @mklimesk I'm trying to implement it but the itemsCopy returns empty in the filter method. I did initialized it to itemsCopy.addAll()

Comment: @mklimek I have a similar Adapter set-up.  When items.clear(); is run it wipes out my View for the RecyclerView CardViews that I have.  If I close the app and then re-open the CardViews are shown and the SearchView works properly.  Any thoughts on why and how to maintain the View?

Comment: Note that you lose the animation if you follow this approach instead of @Xaver Kapeller answer.

Comment: Didn't try the accepted answer because it is way too lengthy. This answer works and easy to implement. Don't forget to add "
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" on your menu item XML.

Comment: @mklimek  Nice solution.  I used your solution and works nicely.  But can't seem to pass adapter position to next Activity.  Would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027110/recyclerview-wrong-position-in-filtered-list

Comment: saved my life Thank youuu :) , very easy solution, there is no need to monkey with filterable !

Comment: What is exactly items and itemsCopy here?

Comment: what is an item,what does it refer to?

Comment: @Lucky_girl and @ora `items` is a collection of data you provide to `RecyclerView.Adapter`. `itemsCopy` is just a copy for filtering purpose because you don't want to affect original data. Read a RecyclerView guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: @humazed what kind of animation do u talk about please

Comment: the filtering animation... when you type a new search query the resulting list will be different before and after, in Xaver answer you will have a nice animation for this change for free.

Comment: @humazed if you use stableIDs you don't loose the animations though.

Comment: If I use this, when I call items.clear(),  the itemcopy gets cleared too

Comment: if you enter a query for which nothing will be found, there will be an error when updating the list

Comment: This works perfectly and is simple, please mark this as an accepted answer. The accepted answer is too complicated to  implement.

Comment: I commented `notifyDataSetChanged();`, and added `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` in `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChanged` before returning true.

Comment: if you have SQLite Database, then replace `itemsCopy()` with your method to get all your item collections like `db.getAllItems()`. Add the second parameter `filter(String text, DatabaseHelper db)` alsa.

Comment: @David Can you explain how to get the animation back? I would love to have the animation along with the simple implementation.

Comment: After setting up adapter, if you will add new items in your original array list on parent activity, new items won't reflect in recycler view.

Answer (score 91):

Following @Shruthi Kamoji in a cleaner way, we can just use a filterable, its meant for that:

```
public abstract class GenericRecycleAdapter<E> extends RecyclerView.Adapter implements Filterable
{
    protected List<E> list;
    protected List<E> originalList;
    protected Context context;

    public GenericRecycleAdapter(Context context,
    List<E> list)
    {
        this.originalList = list;
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                list = (List<E>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                List<E> filteredResults = null;
                if (constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filteredResults = originalList;
                } else {
                    filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint.toString().toLowerCase());
                }

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }
        };
    }

    protected List<E> getFilteredResults(String constraint) {
        List<E> results = new ArrayList<>();

        for (E item : originalList) {
            if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint)) {
                results.add(item);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

The E here is a Generic Type, you can extend it using your class:

```
public class customerAdapter extends GenericRecycleAdapter<CustomerModel>
```

Or just change the E to the type you want (`<CustomerModel>` for example)

Then from searchView (the widget you can put on menu.xml):

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
        yourAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I use something like this! Works fine and generic sample!

Comment: Hello, who can help me step-y-step with this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754174/android-implementing-search-filter-to-a-recyclerview

Comment: The cleanest answer!

Comment: This is much better than the up voted answer because the operation is done on a worker thread in the performFiltering method.

Comment: But you assign a reference to the same List to different variables. For example this.originalList = list; 
You should use addAll instead or pass the list in the ArrayList constructor

Comment: the best answer, works perfectly. Succinct, concise and to the point.

Comment: Wondering how item.getName() works for generic E in getFilteredResults method.

Comment: @crack_head In my case, I had a .getName() method on the class that I used for E. Let's say it was a List<CustomerModel> and CustomerModel has the name property, which has its get and set. But that part of the code is up to you, the requirements are only to return a list from getFilteredResults().

Comment: 5 years later, still very useful and easy to implement. My thanks.

Comment: easy and clear.. thank u

Answer (score 10):

In Adapter:

```
public void setFilter(List<Channel> newList){
        mChannels = new ArrayList<>();
        mChannels.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

In Activity:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                newText = newText.toLowerCase();
                ArrayList<Channel> newList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Channel channel: channels){
                    String channelName = channel.getmChannelName().toLowerCase();
                    if (channelName.contains(newText)){
                        newList.add(channel);
                    }
                }
                mAdapter.setFilter(newList);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: very easy and simple thank you firoz

Answer (score 6):

> simply create two list in adapter one orignal and one temp and **implements Filterable**.

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<T> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (origList == null)
                    origList = new ArrayList<>(itemList);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (origList != null && origList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final T cd : origList) {
                            if (cd.getAttributeToSearch().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size();//newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = origList;
                    oReturn.count = origList.size();//newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                itemList = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<T>) results.values);
                // FIXME: 8/16/2017 implement Comparable with sort below
                ///Collections.sort(itemList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

where

```
public GenericBaseAdapter(Context mContext, List<T> itemList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.origList = itemList;
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution.  I created two lists and used a simple filter method.  I can't seem to pass the correct adapter position for an item to the next Activity.  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas you could suggest for this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027110/recyclerview-wrong-position-in-filtered-list

Answer (score 4):

With *Android Architecture Components* through the use of *LiveData* this can be easily implemented with any type of *Adapter*. You simply have to do the following steps:

**1.** Setup your data to return from the *Room* *Database* as *LiveData* as in the example below:

```
@Dao
public interface CustomDAO{

@Query("SELECT * FROM words_table WHERE column LIKE :searchquery")
    public LiveData<List<Word>> searchFor(String searchquery);
}
```

**2.** Create a *ViewModel* object to update your data live through a method that will connect your *DAO* and your *UI*

```
public class CustomViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final AppDatabase mAppDatabase;

    public WordListViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        this.mAppDatabase = AppDatabase.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public LiveData<List<Word>> searchQuery(String query) {
        return mAppDatabase.mWordDAO().searchFor(query);
    }

}
```

**3.** Call your data from the *ViewModel* on the fly by passing in the query through onQueryTextListener as below:

Inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` set your listener as follows

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(onQueryTextListener);
```

Setup your query listener somewhere in your SearchActivity class as follows

```
private android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener onQueryTextListener =
            new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    getResults(query);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    getResults(newText);
                    return true;
                }

                private void getResults(String newText) {
                    String queryText = "%" + newText + "%";
                    mCustomViewModel.searchQuery(queryText).observe(
                            SearchResultsActivity.this, new Observer<List<Word>>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Word> words) {
                                    if (words == null) return;
                                    searchAdapter.submitList(words);
                                }
                            });
                }
            };
```

**Note**: Steps (1.) and (2.) are standard *AAC ViewModel* and *DAO* implementation, the only real "magic" going on here is in the *OnQueryTextListener* which will update the results of your list dynamically as the query text changes.

If you need more clarification on the matter please don't hesitate to ask.
I hope this helped :).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why everyone is using 2 copies of the same list to solve this. This uses too much RAM...

Why not just **hide** the elements that are not found, and simply store their **index** in a `Set` to be able to restore them later? That's much less RAM especially if your objects are quite large.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.SampleViewHolders>{
    private List<MyObject> myObjectsList; //holds the items of type MyObject
    private Set<Integer> foundObjects; //holds the indices of the found items

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<MyObject> myObjectsList)
    {
        this.myObjectsList = myObjectsList;
        this.foundObjects = new HashSet<>();
        //first, add all indices to the indices set
        for(int i = 0; i < this.myObjectsList.size(); i++)
        {
            this.foundObjects.add(i);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SampleViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.my_layout_for_staggered_grid, null);
        MyRecyclerViewAdapter.SampleViewHolders rcv = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter.SampleViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SampleViewHolders holder, int position)
    {
        //look for object in O(1) in the indices set
        if(!foundObjects.contains(position))
        {
            //object not found => hide it.
            holder.hideLayout();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //object found => show it.
            holder.showLayout();
        }

        //holder.imgImageView.setImageResource(...)
        //holder.nameTextView.setText(...)
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myObjectsList.size();
    }

    public void findObject(String text)
    {
        //look for "text" in the objects list
        for(int i = 0; i < myObjectsList.size(); i++)
        {
            //if it's empty text, we want all objects, so just add it to the set.
            if(text.length() == 0)
            {
                foundObjects.add(i);
            }
            else
            {
                //otherwise check if it meets your search criteria and add it or remove it accordingly
                if (myObjectsList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    foundObjects.add(i);
                }
                else
                {
                    foundObjects.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class SampleViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        public ImageView imgImageView;
        public TextView nameTextView;

        private final CardView layout;
        private final CardView.LayoutParams hiddenLayoutParams;
        private final CardView.LayoutParams shownLayoutParams;

        
        public SampleViewHolders(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            imgImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.some_image_view);
            nameTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.display_name_textview);

            layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view); //card_view is the id of my androidx.cardview.widget.CardView in my xml layout
            //prepare hidden layout params with height = 0, and visible layout params for later - see hideLayout() and showLayout()
            hiddenLayoutParams = new CardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            hiddenLayoutParams.height = 0;
            shownLayoutParams = new CardView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            //implement...
        }

        private void hideLayout() {
            //hide the layout
            layout.setLayoutParams(hiddenLayoutParams);
        }

        private void showLayout() {
            //show the layout
            layout.setLayoutParams(shownLayoutParams);
        }
    }
}
```

And I simply have an `EditText` as my search box:

```
cardsSearchTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                myViewAdapter.findObject(editable.toString().toLowerCase());
            }
        });
```

**Result:**

[image: Search example gif]

Comment: I just give it a try and when I have a list with more than 2000 items there is a lag because it searches on the main list not on the filtered one. but thank you anyway I will use when I have small lists ;)

Comment: Oh thanks for giving it a chance! I didn't try it for such large lists, you're probably right.

Comment: It does not use that much more RAM since the list only holds the reference to the objects, i.e. it does not copy the whole object.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the same problem using the link with some modifications in it. [Search filter on RecyclerView with Cards. Is it even possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792187/search-filter-on-recyclerview-with-cards-is-it-even-possible/29792313#29792313) (hope this helps).

Here is my adapter class

```
public class ContactListRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListRecyclerAdapter.ContactViewHolder> implements Filterable {

Context mContext;
ArrayList<Contact> customerList;
ArrayList<Contact> parentCustomerList;


public ContactListRecyclerAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Contact> customerList)
{
    this.mContext=context;
    this.customerList=customerList;
    if(customerList!=null)
    parentCustomerList=new ArrayList<>(customerList);
}

   // other overrided methods

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new FilterCustomerSearch(this,parentCustomerList);
}
}
```

//Filter class

```
import android.widget.Filter;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FilterCustomerSearch extends Filter
{
private final ContactListRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
ArrayList<Contact> filteredList;

public FilterCustomerSearch(ContactListRecyclerAdapter mAdapter,ArrayList<Contact> contactList) {
    this.mAdapter = mAdapter;
    this.contactList=contactList;
    filteredList=new ArrayList<>();
}

@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    filteredList.clear();
    final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

    if (constraint.length() == 0) {
        filteredList.addAll(contactList);
    } else {
        final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

        for (final Contact contact : contactList) {
            if (contact.customerName.contains(constraint)) {
                filteredList.add(contact);
            }
            else if (contact.emailId.contains(constraint))
            {
                filteredList.add(contact);

            }
            else if(contact.phoneNumber.contains(constraint))
                filteredList.add(contact);
        }
    }
    results.values = filteredList;
    results.count = filteredList.size();
    return results;
}

@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
    mAdapter.customerList.clear();
    mAdapter.customerList.addAll((ArrayList<Contact>) results.values);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

//Activity class

```
public class HomeCrossFadeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,OnFragmentInteractionListener,OnTaskCompletedListner
{
Fragment fragment;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homecrossfadeslidingpane2);CardView mCard;
   setContentView(R.layout.your_main_xml);}
   //other overrided methods
  @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_customer_view_and_search, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Customer");
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if(fragment instanceof CustomerDetailsViewWithModifyAndSearch)
                ((CustomerDetailsViewWithModifyAndSearch)fragment).adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });



    return true;
}
}
```

In OnQueryTextChangeListener() method use your adapter. I have casted it to fragment as my adpter is in fragment. You can use the adapter directly if its in your activity class.

Answer (score 1):

This is my take on expanding @klimat answer to not losing filtering animation.

```
public void filter(String query){
    int completeListIndex = 0;
    int filteredListIndex = 0;
    while (completeListIndex < completeList.size()){
        Movie item = completeList.get(completeListIndex);
        if(item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(query)){
            if(filteredListIndex < filteredList.size()) {
                Movie filter = filteredList.get(filteredListIndex);
                if (!item.getName().equals(filter.getName())) {
                    filteredList.add(filteredListIndex, item);
                    notifyItemInserted(filteredListIndex);
                }
            }else{
                filteredList.add(filteredListIndex, item);
                notifyItemInserted(filteredListIndex);
            }
            filteredListIndex++;
        }
        else if(filteredListIndex < filteredList.size()){
            Movie filter = filteredList.get(filteredListIndex);
            if (item.getName().equals(filter.getName())) {
                filteredList.remove(filteredListIndex);
                notifyItemRemoved(filteredListIndex);
            }
        }
        completeListIndex++;
    }
}
```

Basically what it does is looking through a complete list and adding/removing items to a filtered list one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend modify the solution of @Xaver Kapeller with 2 things below to avoid a problem after you cleared the searched text (the filter didn't work anymore) due to the list back of adapter has smaller size than filter list and the IndexOutOfBoundsException happened. So the code need to modify as below

```
public void addItem(int position, ExampleModel model) {
    if(position >= mModel.size()) {
        mModel.add(model);
        notifyItemInserted(mModel.size()-1);
    } else {
        mModels.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
}
```

And modify also in moveItem functionality

```
public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final ExampleModel model = mModels.remove(fromPosition);
    if(toPosition >= mModels.size()) {
        mModels.add(model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, mModels.size()-1);
    } else {
        mModels.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition); 
    }
}
```

Hope that It could help you!

Comment: That is not at all necessary.

Comment: For original answer if you don't do that the IndexOutOfBoundsException will be happened, so why doesn't necessary ???? Do you want a log ? @XaverKapeller

Comment: No the exception will only happen if you are implementing the `Adapter` the wrong way. Without seeing your code I guess the most likely issue is that you are not passing a copy of the list with all items to the `Adapter`.

Comment: The error log:
W/System.err: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 36, size is 35
W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
W/System.err:     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:147)
W/System.err:     at com.quomodo.inploi.ui.adapter.MultipleSelectFilterAdapter.addItem(MultipleSelectFilterAdapter.java:125)
W/System.err:     at com.quomodo.inploi.ui.adapter.MultipleSelectFilterAdapter.applyAndAnimateAdditions(MultipleSelectFilterAdapter.java:78)

Comment: Please help to check source code below @XaverKapeller
https://gist.github.com/toidv/fe71dc45169e4138271b52fdb29420c5

Comment: There is tons of code in this gist that has nothing to do with the `Adapter` however the important parts I need to help you are missing. I assume `MultipleSelectFilterAdapter` is the class which causes you problems? To be more precise the class which extends `MultipleSelectFilterAdapter`? How is `setItem()` implemented in `MultipleSelectKeySkillAdapter`? That could be where the problem is located. Anyway are you using this in a production app? My original answer was never intended to be used in production. It was an example to explain how item animations work in a `RecyclerView`.

Comment: If you want a production ready solution take a look at my answer again. I updated it today as well as the Github repository containing the example project. You can find the example GitHub repository [**here**](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo).

Comment: Thanks for your new version @XaverKapeller, I will check. Anyway, you could check the setItem in ExampleFragment class
items = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.skill_list));
adapter.setItem(items);

Comment: What I meant was that I need to see the implementation of `setItem()`, not its usage.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding @XaverKapeller. I added file MultipleSelectImplementationAdapter.java for implementation of setItem

Answer (score 0):

[image: Recyclerview with searchview and clicklistener]

Add an interface in your adapter.

```
public interface SelectedUser{

    void selectedUser(UserModel userModel);

}
```

implement the interface in your mainactivity and override the method.
    @Override
    public void selectedUser(UserModel userModel) {

```
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SelectedUserActivity.class).putExtra("data",userModel));



}
```

Full tutorial and source code:
[Recyclerview with searchview and onclicklistener](https://youtu.be/ujKDN_ZtGHQ?sub_confirmation=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search on button click then this works fine.

```
filterIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String strCHR = homeSearchEdit.getText().toString();
        if (homeSearchEdit.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<ServiceModel> listNew = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int l = 0; l < arrayList.size(); l++) {
                String serviceName = arrayList.get(l).getServiceName().toLowerCase();
                if (serviceName.contains(strCHR.toLowerCase())) {
                    listNew.add(arrayList.get(l));
                }
            }
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapter = new ServiceAdapter(HomeActivity.this, listNew);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adapter = new ServiceAdapter(HomeActivity.this, arrayList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
});
```

**where** ,***filterIcon*** is button  and **homeSearchEdit** is editText(where we apply for search).

Answer (score 0):

Android has provided `DiffUtil.Callback()` and `DiffUtil.ItemCallback<T>` and they help us filter our recycler view nicely

> DiffUtil is a utility class that calculates the difference between two
> lists and outputs a list of update operations that converts the first
> list into the second one.
>
> https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil

DiffUtil.Callback() is used with RecyclerView.Adapter

and

DiffUtil.ItemCallback is used with ListAdapter

### **Filter using RecyclerView**

Create your RecyclerView Like you normally would overriding the

```
onCreateViewHolder

onBindViewHolder

getItemCount
```

and extending the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder Class`

Just Like you have done(This is the Kotlin version of snippets from your code)

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): ViewHolder? {
    val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
    val movie: Movie = mItems.get(i)
    viewHolder.tvMovie.setText(movie.getName())
    viewHolder.tvMovieRating.setText(movie.getRating())
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mItems.size()
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var tvMovie: TextView
    var tvMovieRating: TextView

    init {
        tvMovie = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.movieName) as TextView
        tvMovieRating = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.movieRating) as TextView
    }
}
```

Now Create another class which will implement the DiffUtil.Callback()

This class will help convert the recyclerviews currentlist to the filtered list

```
class MoviesDiffUtilCallback(private val oldList: List<Movies>, private val newList: List<Movies>) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

override fun getOldListSize() = oldList.size

override fun getNewListSize() = newList.size

override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) = oldList[oldItemPosition].aUniqueId == newList[newItemPosition]. aUniqueId

//aUniqueId-> a field that is unique to each item in your listItems

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) = oldList[oldItemPosition] == newList[newItemPosition]

}
```

In your Activity or Fragment Class Setup your adapter and your filter

```
private fun setupAdapter() {

//mItems is the list you will pass to the adapter
        adapter = CardAdapter(mItems)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

}

fun filter(searchText : String){

    val newFilter = mItems.filter {

        it.name.lowercase().contains(text.lowercase()) //filterlogic

    }

//Calculate the list of update operations that can covert one list into the other one 
    val diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(PostsDiffUtilCallback(mItems,newFilter))

    mItems.clear()


    mItems.addAll(newFilter)

//dispatch all updates to the RecyclerView
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(adapter)

}
```

### **Filter using ListAdapter**

We will be using the filterable interface to help us filter (still figuring out why I shouldn't just use a filter function to get filteredLists and submitList(filteredLists) Directly)

Create your ListAdapter class

```
class CardAdapter (
private val mItems : List<Movies>) : ListAdapter<Movies, CardAdapter.BillsPackageViewHolder>(MoviesDiffCallback()),
Filterable {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, i: Int): ViewHolder? {
    val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_card_item, viewGroup, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)
}

fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, i: Int) {
    val movie: Movie = mItems.get(i)
    viewHolder.tvMovie.setText(movie.getName())
    viewHolder.tvMovieRating.setText(movie.getRating())
}


override fun getFilter(): Filter {

    return object : Filter() {

        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {

            return FilterResults().apply {

                values = if (constraint.isNullOrEmpty())
                    mItems
                else
                    onFilter(mItems, constraint.toString())
            }
        }

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {

            submitList(results?.values as? List<Movies>)

        }
    }

}

fun onFilter(list: List<Movies>, constraint: String) : List<Movies>{

    val filteredList = list.filter {

        it.name.lowercase().contains(constraint.lowercase())

    }

    return filteredList

}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var tvMovie: TextView
    var tvMovieRating: TextView

    init {
        tvMovie = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.movieName) as TextView
        tvMovieRating = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.movieRating) as TextView
    }
}
}
```

Now Create another class which will implement the DiffUtil.ItemCallback

```
class MoviesDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Movies>() {

override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Movies, newItem: Movies): Boolean {
    return oldItem.someUniqueid == newItem.someUniqueid
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Movies, newItem: Movies): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
}
}
```

and in your MainActivity or Fragment Setup your adapter and your filter

```
private fun setupAdapter() {

    adapter = CardAdapter(mItems)

    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

}

fun filter(searchString : String){

    adapter.filter.filter(searchString)

}
```