# Searching in recycler view returns different position when i click?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

[How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

I followed the above answered recyclerview search. I have one problem, whenever i search and  click on the items it returns to different position provided that i could get that particular item id,name,etc.

Answer (score 0):

You might try Parse.com. It gives you the possibility to create a database.
Getting the data from Parse.com can be done by the ParseSDK or normal requests.
If you would like to use normal requests, Retrofit is a nice library to help you with that.