# Reset List on SearchView clear

Tags: android, list, searchview

I have a `SearchView`. I filter `RecyclerView` according to the string inside the `SearchView`. The filtering is fine. But I want to reset the list to the original once the `SearchView` 'X' is clicked.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 searchM.QueryTextChange += searchCheckin_QueryTextChange;
 void searchMe_QueryTextChange(object sender, Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewText))
            {
                filteredModelList = filter(dupes, e.NewText);
                mAdapter.AnimateTo(filteredModelList);
                mRecyclerView.ScrollToPosition(0);
            }
            else
            {
                searchMe.SetQuery("",false);
            }


        }
```

But this doesnt work and just clears the `SearchView` and does not show the original list.

How can I solve this and show the original list once the `SearchView` is cleared?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

Comment: Just reset the original data (full data) in else block.

Comment: @Rami I already have checked the question you mentioned. But I cant seem to get the reset workin

Comment: That was EmptyCup who mentioned the question. Post your adapter code.