# Android recyclerview filter showing no items until searchview icon is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, filter, android-recyclerview, android-search

I have a fragment in which I do a network call and populate the contained recycler view with cards. Now I followed [this](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo) to add a filter to my recycler view. Now the problem arises when in the adapter constructor I do

```
this.storeLists = new ArrayList<>(storeLists);
```

the List in my fragment gets populated but doesn't show any item until I click the searchview icon and start typing something. After that even if I close the searchview the list retains.

I tried changing the above line to

```
this.storeLists = storeLists;
```

when I remove the search query the deleted items are not re shown. So in case if I search something non - existent in my recycler view list, I am left with nothing showing in my recycler view.

What I want is that when I open the fragment I see the result and then when I click the search icon and start typing the filters work as shown in the link above.

**EDIT**:

[Here](https://github.com/D8thReaper/BrinjalClient/blob/master/app/src/main/java/exun/cli/in/brinjal/adapter/RVStoreAdapter.java) is my adapter and [here](https://github.com/D8thReaper/BrinjalClient/blob/master/app/src/main/java/exun/cli/in/brinjal/activity/fragment/Store.java) is my calling fragment.

Comment: I can understand what your problem is and i faces the same issue. If you show me your code it will be easier for me to pin point the issue

Comment: @RageshRamesh edited and added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hit and trial I found the solution at the cost of the cool animation. For now the code segment works by just resetting the adapter like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    Log.d(TAG,newText);
    searchStoreList = storeList;
    final List<StoreList> filteredModelList = filter(searchStoreList, newText);
    //((RVStoreAdapter) mAdapter).animateTo(filteredModelList);
    //The above commented line is the old code. Following is how to reset the adapter!
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new RVStoreAdapter(getActivity(),storeList,session.getLat(),session.getLongi());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
    return true;
}
```

The animation is now very abrupt but the solution resets the list on changing the search query accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this.storeLists = new ArrayList<>(storeLists); and hence notifyDatasetChanged wont work as you are using a new list altogether.

But you shouldnt change it as you need the keep the storeLists as it contains your full data. What you can do is  create a method as below in your adapter

```
 public void setList(ArrayList<StoreList> mList){
   this.storeList = mList;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

And in your fragment once you have downloaded data and added to your storelist, call setList method as follows

```
 mAdapter.setList(storeList);
```

also remove mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in your storeReq method as it does nothing.

Comment: The problem persists as I set the List in adapter = mList that the deletion of items will not bring the previously excluded items back. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841163/recyclerview-filter-not-working