# RecyclerView: wrong position in filtered List

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have a RecyclerView list of CardView items.  I then use a simple filter method with a SearchView widget to filter the list.  When I then click on a filtered CardView to launch a CardViewDetails Activity, the UI is showing the CardView from the original List and not the filtered List.  For example, I have a list of twenty items in the original List.  When I enter a search constraint the filtered List correctly shows three CardViews in the RecyclerView.  When I click on the third CardView in the List, the UI returns the third CardView from the original List and not the third CardView from the filtered List.  What am I missing here?

```
Adapter:

public class MyRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private List<ListItem> mListItems, filteredList;
Context mContext;
private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
/**********************************************************/
private String searchString = "";
/**********************************************************/

public MyRecylerAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> listItems) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mListItems = listItems;
    this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.filteredList.addAll(this.mListItems);
}

// RecyclerItemClickListener is the public interface file used to reach the MainActivity
public void setOnItemClickListener(RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener) {
    this.recyclerItemClickListener = recyclerItemClickListener;
}

// Get the Item's position.
public ListItem getItem(int position) {
    return filteredList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (filteredList.size() >0) {
        return filteredList.size();
    }
    else {
        return mListItems.size();
    }
}

public void setFilter(List<ListItem> listItems, String searchString) {
    // Note: the String is to get s.toString() from the Main Activity SearchView.
    filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    filteredList.addAll(listItems);
    this.searchString = searchString;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_contact_item, parent, false);
    final ItemHolder itemHolder = new ItemHolder(view);

        // Attach a Click listener to the items's (row) view.
        // itemView is from the ItemHolder() below.
        // onItemClick is the click method in MainActivity.
        itemHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int adapterPos = itemHolder.getAdapterPosition(); // get the item position.                    
                if (adapterPos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    if (recyclerItemClickListener != null) {
                        // pass the item to the Main Activity
                        // through the RecyclerItemClickListener file and its
                        // public interface.
                        recyclerItemClickListener.onItemClick(itemHolder.itemView,adapterPos);
                    }
                }
            }
        });            
    return itemHolder;
}

private static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView cardBlankText2; 

    private ItemHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardBlankText2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardBlankText2);            
}

public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ListItem listItem = filteredList.get(position);
    final ItemHolder itemHolder = (ItemHolder) holder;

    itemHolder.cardBlankText2.setText(listItem.getTodo());
}

Activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    RecyclerItemClickListener {

private List<ListItem> allList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private SQLiteDB sqLiteDB;
private MyRecylerAdapter adapter;    
private CardView cardview;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sqLiteDB = SQLiteDB.getInstance(this);        
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.list_recyclerview);        
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);        
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    allList = sqLiteDB.getAllDBItems();

    adapter = new MyRecylerAdapter(this, allList);
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
    cardview = (CardView) view;
    cardview.setEnabled(false);

    // Create a new intent to send data from this MainActivity to the CardViewDetails
    // Activity.
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,CardViewDetails.class);
    ListItem listItem = adapter.getItem(position);
    // Add the item object to the Intent.  The item object can be used because the
    // model class implements Parcelable so it holds all of the getters
    // that can be snagged in the next Activity with the
    // getParcelableExtra method.
    intent.putExtra("item",listItem);
    intent.putExtra("position",position);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

// SearchView
final EditText mSearchEditText = (EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);

    mSearchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

             final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList = filter(allList, s.toString());

                if (!mSearchView.isIconified() && filteredModelList.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // re-load the list so the Adapter refreshes the RecyclerView list View.
                    adapter.clear();
                    adapter.addAll(allList);
                } else if (!mSearchView.isIconified() && filteredModelList.size() > 0) {                            
                    adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList, s.toString());
                    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
                }
            }
        }
    });

private ArrayList<ListItem> filter(List<ListItem> models, String query) {

    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final ArrayList<ListItem> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ListItem listItem : models) {
        final String text = listItem.getTodo().toLowerCase();
        final String text2 = listItem.getNote1().toLowerCase();
        final String text3 = listItem.getNote2().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query) || text2.contains(query) ||
            text3.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(listItem);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}

RecyclerItemClickListener:

public interface RecyclerItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

CardViewDetails:

public class CardViewDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

private int position;
private SQLiteDB helper;
List<ListItem> listItems;
private CardView cardview;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.dets);

    // Create a variable for the skychill footer text.
    final TextView skychilltext5;

    // A db helper instance is needed for the removeItem() below
    // when the user Longclicks the skycard for deletion.
    helper = new SQLiteDB(this);

    // Get the position of the clicked on R. list CardView from
    // the MainActivity's intent bundle.
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        // get the CardView item using the int position from the
        // MainActivity's onItemClick() and the putExtra in the intent.
        position = extras.getInt("position",0); // 0 is default value
    }

    cb2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cb2);

    helper = new SQLiteDB(this);
    listItems = new ArrayList<>();
    listItems = helper.getAllDBItems(); 

    cb2.setText(listItems.get(position).getTodo());

    ...

}
```

Comment: When passing the click event to the MainActivity, the MainActivity might still use the "old", unfiltered list instead of the filtered list to determine the item to act upon?

Comment: @Ascorbin Probably the case.  I'm stuck on how to fix.  Any ideas?

Comment: Might have, if you post the relevant part(s) of you MainActivity ;)

Comment: I posted MainActivity's onCreate and onItemClick methods.  I can add the Model class and the DetailsActivity.

Comment: I suspect, when setting the clickListener on the viewHolder, retrieving the position with getAdapterPosition does not what you'd like it to do. 
Can you try setting the clickListener in onBindViewHolder and using the position of the onBindViewHolder method parameter instead of using getAdapterPosition?

Comment: I thought about that but since onBindViewHolder is constantly re-binding views it would require constantly re-binding the clickListener too which would degrade performance.  So I am searching for another way.

Comment: Setting the clickListener would not have any noticable effect on performance I reckon. Have you tested that it has?

Comment: I haven't tested...There have been a number of stackoverflow posters who put the clickListener in onBindViewHolder.  I just read a lot of articles, tutorials and stackoverflow comments that recommend the clickListener be in the ViewHolder for performance reasons.

Comment: Mh, you're right, and getAdapterposition seems to work as expected. 
The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: The answer by "abest" might be the issue here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40747468/recyclerview-search-filter-getting-wrong-position  What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After applying filter the sql DB (**getAllDBItems** ) data remain same. You are passing only `position` to **CardViewDetail**. And the sql data is of original list.

You should pass your **ListItem as parcelable** to `CardViewDetails` instead of position. your problem will be solved.

Comment: Very good and exactly how I achieved.  Last piece I am struggling with is how to update the View on CardViewDetails when the user edits data.  I've asked a new question here:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046633/recyclerview-how-to-refresh-details-activity  I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas on how to solve.