# How to filter Recyclerview with SearchView on multiple parameters

Tags: filter, parameters, android-recyclerview, searchview

I have implemented the SearchView example given here.

[How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

....to filter and list company names based on the parameter "Product name".

In my project, I want to extend this to further filter on the parameter on "city name"

The below is the code for the onQueryTextSubmit which filters on the parameter "productname".

@Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

```
private List<ExampleModel> filter(List<ExampleModel> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<ExampleModel> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ExampleModel model : models) {
        final String text = model.getText().toLowerCase();
        final String city = model.getCity().toLowerCase();
        final String product = model.getProduct().toLowerCase();
        final String services = model.getServices().toLowerCase();
        final String state = model.getState().toLowerCase();
        final String zone = model.getZone().toLowerCase();
        if (product.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }

    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

How should I go forward from here?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the city name verification here:

```
    if (product.contains(query) || city.contains(query)) {
        filteredModelList.add(model);
    }
```