# filter recyclerview using searchview

Tags: java, android

**Solved , I should use Static for my Models in declerating . thanks all**

I just went through this topic [filter recycler view using search view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439/2310866) and I did all the steps. Now when I search in recycler view it will filter my recycler view but when I press back space and remove a char it wont show the removed items! My recycler view is also empty after the search.

This is my RecyclerView adapter:

```
package com.webapp.masoud.application.myRecyclerAdapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.webapp.masoud.application.R;
import com.webapp.masoud.application.service.NewsModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class myRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myRecyclerAdapter.myRecyclerViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
     ArrayList<NewsModel> myModels;
    public myRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewsModel> myModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.myModels = myModels;
    }

    @Override
    public myRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.channels_layout, parent, false);
        return new myRecyclerViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final NewsModel newsModel = myModels.get(position);
        holder.edt_Title.setText(newsModel.title);
        holder.edt_Dis.setText(newsModel.discription);
        holder.txt_Category.setText(newsModel.category);
        Picasso.with(context).load(newsModel.image).into(holder.img_Channel);
        holder.btn_Join.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username;
                if (newsModel.username.startsWith("@")){
                    username = "http://telegram.me/" + newsModel.username.substring(1);
                    }
                else{
                username = "http://telegram.me/" + newsModel.username;}
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(username));
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myModels.size();
    }


    public void animateTo(ArrayList<NewsModel> models) {
        applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
        applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
        applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
    }

    public void setModels(ArrayList<NewsModel> models) {
        myModels = new ArrayList<>(models);
    }

    public NewsModel removeItem(int position) {
        final NewsModel model = myModels.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return model;
    }

    public void addItem(int position, NewsModel model) {
        myModels.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final NewsModel model = myModels.remove(fromPosition);
        myModels.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }




    private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(ArrayList<NewsModel> newModels) {
        for (int i = myModels.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final NewsModel model = myModels.get(i);
            if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
    private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(ArrayList<NewsModel> newModels) {
        for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
            final NewsModel model = newModels.get(i);
            if (!myModels.contains(model)) {
                addItem(i, model);
            }
        }
    }
    private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(ArrayList<NewsModel> newModels) {
        for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
            final NewsModel model = newModels.get(toPosition);
            final int fromPosition = myModels.indexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        }
    }


    class myRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView edt_Title;
        private TextView edt_Dis;
        public TextView txt_Category;
        private Button btn_Join;
        private CircleImageView img_Channel;
        public myRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
             edt_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_Title);
             edt_Dis = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_Dis);
             btn_Join = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_Join);
             img_Channel = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_Channel);
            txt_Category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_Category);

        }
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
package com.webapp.masoud.application.Activity;


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.webapp.masoud.application.R;
import com.webapp.masoud.application.myRecyclerAdapter.myRecyclerAdapter;
import com.webapp.masoud.application.service.NewsModel;
import com.webapp.masoud.application.service.APIService;
import com.webapp.masoud.application.service.NewsModelResponse;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyContextWrapper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem searchMenuItem;
     RecyclerView rv_Channels;
    private Parcelable recyclerViewState;
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener myListener;
    myRecyclerAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<NewsModel> newsModelArrayList;
    NewsModelResponse newsModelResponse;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //CalliGraphy
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Vazir.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build()
        );
        //Context
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //MY Application
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        final ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        myProgressDialog.setMessage("در حال دریافت لیست کانال ها ، لطفا منتظر بمانید .");
         rv_Channels = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_Channels);
        final SearchView sv_Channels = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sv_Channels);

        //My API Service !
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://rapcity1.cf/service/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<NewsModelResponse> serviceNewsModels = service.getNewsModels();


        serviceNewsModels.enqueue(new Callback<NewsModelResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<NewsModelResponse> call, Response<NewsModelResponse> response) {
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();

                newsModelResponse = response.body();

                newsModelArrayList = newsModelResponse.getNewsModels();
                 myAdapter = new myRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, newsModelArrayList);
                LinearLayoutManager myLinearlayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                rv_Channels.setLayoutManager(myLinearlayoutmanager);

                recyclerViewState = rv_Channels.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();//save
                rv_Channels.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                rv_Channels.setAdapter(myAdapter);



            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<NewsModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

        //End of API Service
        //Search
        assert sv_Channels != null;
        myListener =  new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

                final ArrayList<NewsModel> filteredModelList = filter(newsModelArrayList, query);
                myAdapter.animateTo(filteredModelList);
                rv_Channels.scrollToPosition(0);
                return true;

            }
        };

    }
    private ArrayList<NewsModel> filter(ArrayList<NewsModel> models, String query) {
       // query = query.toLowerCase();

        final ArrayList<NewsModel> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (NewsModel model : models) {
            final String title = model.title;
            //final String dis = model.discription;
            if (title.contains(query) /*|| dis.contains(query)*/) {
                filteredModelList.add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(myListener);
        mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                rv_Channels.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my newsModels:

```
package com.webapp.masoud.application.service;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Created by Master on 4/19/2016.
 */

public class NewsModel implements Serializable {


    public String id;
    public String title;

    public String discription;
    public String image;
    public String category;
    public String username;
    public NewsModel(String title, String description,String image,String id,String category,String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.discription = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.category = category;
        this.username=username;
    }

    public NewsModel() {
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks. Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the tutorial and get it done. I just implements my Activity with

```
implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener
```

Also i am using searchview this way.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.close_menu, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

and rest the overrided methods, Not sure although give a try.

Comment: tried not working :( Please help me . ps : Im Using RetroFit 2 .