# SubmitQuery on RecyclerView with images very slow and not work correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

Good day for everybody, I implemented `RecyclerView` with `SearchView`  and the data from web service, In `SearchView` when i clear the some of text or all of text nothing update list and it's very slow to execute query, I follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview) .

> Note : items are contains images !

my filter is very simple does not complex :

```
    private ArrayList<itemObj> filter(ArrayList<itemObj> models, String query) {
    final ArrayList<itemObj> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (itemObj model : models) {
        final String text = model.getTitle();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}
```

any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is after you cleared the searched text, the list back of adapter has smaller size than filter list. So the code need to modify as below

```
public void addItem(int position, ExampleModel model) {
    if(position >= mModel.size()) {
        mModel.add(model);
        notifyItemInserted(mModel.size()-1);
    } else {
        mModels.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
}
```

And modify also in moveItem functionality

```
public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
    final ExampleModel model = mModels.remove(fromPosition);
    if(toPosition >= mModels.size()) {
        mModels.add(model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, mModels.size()-1);
    } else {
        mModels.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition); 
    }
}
```

Hope that It could help you!