# Should we pass a copy of the items to RecyclerView, so that when we filter, we don't remove from the actual list?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 10 items in my activity. 
They are displayed in a RecyclerView.
The itms are stored in a list;

```
List<CustomItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
```

I pass them to the RecyclerView adapter like so:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new RVAdapter(this, items));
```

Now, whenever I do filter the items by a string query, so that the
recycler view displays a subset of the items by description, for instance, 
I have to pass a filtered list of items to the recycler view, like so:

```
List<CustomItem> filteredItems = CustomItem.filterByQuery(items, query);
```

and then I:

```
adapter.setItemList(filteredItems);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

-> which sets the filtered items in place of the `items` I sent to it in the constructor, and effectively overrids the activity `items` because they both point to the same objects in memory.

And I realized that by filtering in order to display a subset of results, I am overriding the acitivy's list of items, because it is shared by the activity and the `RecyclerView`

However, of all the code samples and tutorials I've seen on `RecyclerView`, I've never seen anyone do a deep copy of the list of items and pass it to the RV, so what am I missing here?

Comment: where does your data come from? is it sqlite database or some net api respose?

Comment: I get it from the server, then store it in the DB and pass it to the Activity so that it can store it in memory and work with it

Comment: then use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter, as you can see it is `Filterable` so you can just call `getFilter().filter()` on it

Comment: of course like in "normal" `CursorAdapter` you need either to override `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` or call `setFilterQueryProvider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the comments below the accepted answer here:
[How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

To quote:

> @LalitThapa Just look at the constructor of my ExampleAdapter above. The second line should be interesting for you because that's where I make a copy of the List passed into the Adapter. What you want to have is two separate Lists. One in your Activity or Fragment which contains all items and a second List in your Adapter which contains only the filtered icons. Your problem is that you use the same List instance for both. – Xaver Kapeller Jan 17 at 19:05