# How to implement multiple filtering on RecyclerView based android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-filter

Currently, I have developed an `Activity` to show list of data using `RecyclerView` with searching feature (as seen at image_1).

I want to add filtering option to the toolbar similar to the filter on the Youtube app (see image_2). Can anyone can give me clues to easily implement it? Both for the UI design and business logic.

Any idea how to implement the filter dialog window (see image_3)? Should I just use `AlertDialog` or is there any other better options?

[image: image_1]  [image: image_2]    [image: image_3]

Comment: for easy filtering use [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85/raw/89a41acded0889028be48e1f669562046cf66126/MatchableRVArrayAdapte%2520(pure%2520RecyclerView%2520style,%2520no%2520implicit%2520TextView%2520mapping)) generic adapter

Comment: @pskink That's an awesome class, but I'm not sure how to use it exactly. Would you mind answering with some code?

Comment: @Sam https://pastebin.com/raw/LEena3pM

Answer (score 2):

So, you need to create a options menu that starts a DialogFragment with a custom layout and get the tags filtered by the user in your dialog, then you can use them to filter your recyclerview.

**Your adapter should implements Filterable interface!!**

You can do it by following theses instructions:

1. Create a OptionsMenu that starts your DialogFragment. Create a
2. DialogInterface.OnClickListener to your search button in the dialog
3. that call your adapter.filter by your tags. Create a
4. Filter(android.widget.Filter) that receives your tags and then you
   could filter the data and notify!

**Your adapter has to implements Filterable.**

[How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

Comment: Can you give a sample layout?