# setFilter help needed

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

So basically I am writing creating an `Activity` which shows a list of Beaches in a `RecyclerView`. What is suppose to happen is that on the search menu above when the user begins typing in the Beach they are looking for, the list of beaches narrows eventually to the beach they are looking for. So I am literally on my last line of code for this to be fully functional but I keep getting a error on the `setFilter` part of this line

```
adapter.setFilter(newlist);
```

Below is my code, please advise.

**BeachActivity.java**

```
public class BeachActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    Toolbar toolbarbeach;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    ArrayList<beachesalbum> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String [] b_name = {"South Beach","North Beach","Another Beach","Beachman"};
    int [] b_pic = {R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,R.drawable.b3,R.drawable.b4,};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beach);
        toolbarbeach=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_beaches);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarbeach);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Beaches");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        int count = 0;

        for (String Name :b_name)
        {
            arrayList.add(new beachesalbum(Name,b_pic[count]));
            count++;
        }
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapterBeaches(arrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_items,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.beachsearch);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        newText = newText.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<beachesalbum> newlist = new ArrayList <>();

        for(beachesalbum beachesalbum : arrayList)
        {
            String name = beachesalbum.getName().toLowerCase();
            if (name.contains(newText));
            newlist.add(beachesalbum);
        }
        adapter.setFilter(newlist);

        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see my error is at `adapter.setFilter(newlist);` above

**beachesalbum.java**

```
public class beachesalbum {
    private int img_id;
    private String name;
    public beachesalbum(String name,int img_id)
    {
        this.setName(name);
        this.setImg_id(img_id);
    }

    public int getBeach_id() {
        return beach_id;
    }

    public void setBeach_id(int beach_id) {
        this.beach_id = beach_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private int beach_id;

    beachesalbum(int img_id)
    {
        setImg_id(img_id);
    }



    public int getImg_id() {
        return img_id;
    }

    public void setImg_id(int img_id) {
        this.img_id = img_id;
    }
}
```

AND FINALLY 
**RecyclerAdapterBeaches.java**

```
public class RecyclerAdapterBeaches extends     RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterBeaches.BeachesViewHolder>{
    ArrayList<beachesalbum> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerAdapterBeaches(ArrayList<beachesalbum>arrayList)
    {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }
    @Override
    public BeachesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);

        return new BeachesViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BeachesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.b_pic.setImageResource(arrayList.get(position).getImg_id());
       holder.b_id.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());

    }

    @Override
   public int getItemCount() {

        return arrayList.size();
    }
    public static class BeachesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        ImageView b_pic;
        TextView b_id;

        public BeachesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            b_pic=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.beachpic);
            b_id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.beaches_id);

        }
    }

    public void setFilter(ArrayList<beachesalbum>newlist)
    {arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.addAll(newlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();}
}
```

Please lend your assistance.

Comment: *error on the setFilter* - **What error?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `BeachActivity` you're setting the adapter with `arrayList`. `RecyclerView` adapter keeps the reference of your `arrayList`. So you if you need to filter out some items from your `RecyclerView`, you need to make the changes in the `arrayList`.

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    newText = newText.toLowerCase();

    // Clear the arrayList first.
    arrayList.clear();

    // If the search text is empty, repopulate the arrayList
    if(newText.length == 0) {
        int count = 0;
        for (String Name :b_name) {
            arrayList.add(new beachesalbum(Name,b_pic[count]));
            count++;
        }
    }

    else {
        int count = 0;
        for (String Name :b_name) {
            if(Name.contains(newText))
                arrayList.add(new beachesalbum(Name,b_pic[count]));
            count++;
        }
    }

    adapter.setFilter(arrayList);

    return true;
}
```

And the `setFilter` function in your adapter

```
public void setFilter(ArrayList<beachesalbum> newlist) {
    this.arrayList.clear();
    this.arrayList.addAll(newlist);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Update**

And yes, from the previous answer. You need to take the `RecyclerAdapterBeaches adapter` instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter adapter`. I missed that part. Thanks @loosethinker.

```
RecyclerAdapterBeaches adapter;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setFilter` function doesn't exist for `RecyclerView.Adapter`, which is the type of the `adapter` variable. Since you are always assigning a `RecyclerAdapterBeaches` to it you should just change it's type to that.

Otherwise, it can't ensure that the object has a `setFilter` function.

```
public class BeachActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    Toolbar toolbarbeach;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerAdapterBeaches adapter; // Update this line

    // ...
}
```