# Change sorting order with SortedList and RecyclerView

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview, android-support-library, sortedlist

I'm using a `SortedList` which is used for filtering of the data in the `RecyclerView` in regards to the current query in a `SearchView` as described in [How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview/30429439#30429439).

The problem is that the order of items must be able to change as well. The `SortedList` interacts with the `Adapter` through a `Callback` class that has a `compare` method. I would need to change it if the user changes the way the items are sorted but I am not sure how I can do that.

The current situation calls only for the reversal of the order, so this problem could be solved with a `LinearLayoutManager` with `setReversedLayout(true)` but I would be interested in how I can provide a completely different way of sorting the items in the `SortedList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SortedList` API doesn't support dynamic changes of the conditions under which the list is sorted. It is designed to support changes of sorting criteria of a particular item or a batch of items at once. For example, supported scenario could be when item X priority value increases, and the list is sorted by priority. But not when the sorting condition changes to sorting by date.

Your case is the best solved the way you did, with `setReversedLayout()`. Another (relatively clean) approach could be to instantiate a new SortedList with a different instance of `SortedList.Callback` that supports the new sorting, add all items from the old list, instruct the `ViewHolder` to use the new list instead, and trigger `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change sorting strategy dynamically because sorted list has a single sorted order for each instance(there is no method for "do sorting again").

You can use

```
recyclerView.swapAdapter(newAdapter, false);`
```

If you have stable id's in your adapter, you will get a nice animation. Because `swapAdapter()` helps RecyclerView to re-use view holders.

Answer (score 0):

A trick that I'm using to re-sort the list when an item changes is to remove the item and add it back to the adapter. This seems to be working well for me.