# recycler view list is getting refreshed after search filter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

Hi I have a `recyclerview` where I have `checkboxes` in it. and I have a search filter were I am searching and getting searched items at the top. The problem now is when I click the `checkbox` after filtering the position is getting changed as 0 and and the first item of the list is getting added to the database instead of the searched item.

I have search filter as given in the link..
[Android - Implementing search filter to a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754174/android-implementing-search-filter-to-a-recyclerview)

The result I want is when I select an item after filtering correct position have to be checked the `recyclerview` should not take the old list.

Here is my checkbox onCheckedChangedListerner code:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                        itemsPojo = itemList.get(position);

                if (isChecked) {
                    checked++;
                    noOfItems.setText(String.valueOf(checked));

                    OrderTable orderTable1 = new OrderTable(storeID, storesPojos.getPhone(), storesPojos.getAddress(),
                            add, itemsPojo.getProduct(), itemsPojo.getManufacturer());
                    dbHelper.insertItemsInOrderTable(orderTable1);

                } else {
                    Log.e("Coming here...////","!!!@@@@@###$$$%%%%^^^&&&&&&***(((");
                    checked--;
                    noOfItems.setText(String.valueOf(checked));                        dbHelper.deleteItemFromOrderTable(itemsPojo.getItemCode(),storeID);
                }
            }
        });
```

Here while checking the checkbox I am inserting items to database.. what happens is lets assume I am searching for some 100th item and after searching that item the search filter filters and shows that item on the top and I am checking it.. here the position of the adapter is changing from 100 to 0 and once I clear the filter the 0th item is getting checked other than the 100th item.. I am sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: Post your code please, and point out the problem in it