# how to implement search in custom Recyclerview?

Tags: android

need to implement a search feature based on an `EditText` to my `RecyclerView`. The list must be filtered while typing. I have an `edittext` and a `Rexyclerview`  I want `Recyclerview` filter with `edittext`. I searched a lot on google and found some examples but none worked for me here's my code. I need to clear the list before adding the results

```
My search feature is filtering but showing same data

 public void filter(String s) {
            String text;
              text = s.toString().toLo`enter code here`werCase();
            text = text.toLowerCase().trim();


            // text = s.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            mDisplayedValues = new ArrayList<SelectedAthleteDEtail>();
            mDisplayedValues.clear();
            if (text.length() == 0) {
                 mDisplayedValues = AthleteData;
               // mDisplayedValues.addAll(AthleteData);
                BoardRecyclerData.setAdapter(adapter);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                mDisplayedValues.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                for (SelectedAthleteDEtail cs : AthleteData) {
                         if (cs.getFirstName().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                          mDisplayedValues.add(cs);
                             Log.d(TAG, "filterab: "+cs.getFirstName());
                             Log.d(TAG, "filterxyz: "+mDisplayedValues);
                        }
                    }
                }
                BoardRecyclerData.setAdapter(adapter);
                //notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754174/android-implementing-search-filter-to-a-recyclerview

Comment: Why you call BoardRecyclerData.setAdapter(adapter);? it call again and again. Did you publish filtered result? I find that in your filter has no return type

Answer (score 0):

I think SearchView is what You need.

[There](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OU9PEL4e7V0) is a nice tut.