# What is the ItemExampleBinding object in this project?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have been looking around on SO and GitHub to find a convenient way to search through my RecyclerView.

I have found this project: [Searchable RecyclerView](https://wrdlbrnft.github.io/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo/)

This is the GitHub repo: [repo](https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo)

And this is a SO answer that explains how to use it: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439/6427630)

It seems really easy to use but in the `ViewHolder.class` there is this code:

```
private final ItemExampleBinding mBinding;
```

with this ItemExampleBinding object, that isn't mentioned anywhere, not on SO, nor on GitHub, nor on the project Homepage.

**Have any of you used this Library before and can explain to me what this Object is and how to create it?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class `ItemExampleBinding` is auto-generated from Data Binding.

Android provides one library that Binds data to it's view.
It uses `MVVM` pattern instead of traditional `MVP` pattern in Android.

**Traditional Way:**

1. Inflating XML layout in the activity
2. Finding the element in the layout by using a method such as
   findViewbyID,
3. Assigning the element to a local variable,
4. Getting value from the data, and
5. Assigning value to an element property.

**Using DataBinding library:**

1. Create a binding from a layout
2. Retrieve the data
3. Bind the data to the view

For more information, please check references below:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html
http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/how-to-use-android-data-binding.html

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since my app has been under development for a while now and I prefer not to change the whole code as required by Data Binding is there a way I can use this library without data binding or another library that does the same thing?

Comment: @Daniele: Yes you can use same library. You have issue in generating that class. Please clean or rebuild project which will clear the error!

Comment: I tried both, cleaning and rebuilding but I still get "cannot resolve symbol: ItemExampleBinding"

Comment: @Daniele: Can you just remove library and import again. As There may be some issue for library to generate build files!

Answer (score 0):

//It is DataBinding error you do clean and build project to resolve that otherwise rename databinding in xml layout

//I have just implement and work perfect