# Make the SearchView do searches

Tags: android, xml, searchview

I have a `SearchView` up and ready, here is the code I use in the java file of the page that has the `SearchView`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(
                new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), SearchableActivity.class)));


        return true;
    }
```

My goal is now to let this `SearchView` search through a site full of `TextView`s. Every `TextView` contains one word. Is it possible to make the `SearchView` find the `TextView` that contains the word i just typed in? If so, how? If not, how can I make it happen in another way?

Kind regards,
Julian

Comment: try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview

Answer (score 2):

The `SearchView` doesn't do any search at all, it's a simple widget for inputting the keywords, show recently used keywords, etc. You should implement your "search model" to find the content, and display it somewhere you want.

Comment: My bad because of asking the question wrong I guess. So I have everything set up to this point, the next step I have to take is to define Querys or something like that or a virtual table, but I feel like thats not what I am looking for if I want to search for TextViews. So basically the question is, if I should create a virtual table for my goal.

Comment: @user7342339 What do you mean by "search for TextViews"? search the text shown in `TextView` widget? If that's really what you want (instead of search in a model like e.g. a sqlite db), you can use `TextView.getText()` to get the content for each text view widget.

Comment: I have around 40 TextViews that all contain one word. What I wanna do is, to search for the words inside the TextViews, but I am not sure how to tell the SearchViews and everything that is linked to that, what I want to find.

Comment: 40 TextViews were stored in somewhere maybe in list or map or array you have to search there abt the keyword.

Comment: So I have to set up an Array in order to make the textViews "searchable"?

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Activity.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

// Setting up custom search button icon
        int searchImgId = android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_button; // I used the explicit layout ID of searchview's ImageView
        ImageView v = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_black);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Do operation
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```

menu_search.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:appcompat="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black"
        android:title="@string/search"
        appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        appcompat:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: It says, that it cannot resolve method getActivty(), am I making a rookie mistake? :D

Comment: getActivity() can be replaced by your context friend... 

try **getApplicationContext()** or pass **context** instead of getActivity()

if your code is in activity then, remove **getActivity().** if you are using fragment than try solution mentioned as above.

Comment: I see, and what is the goal of the last line? Because (menu, inflate) is also marked red, as onCreateOptionsMenu cannot be applied to androidViewMenuInflate. Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: are you using this code for activity or a fragment? can you tell me? so that i can help you accordingly

Comment: I am using this code as a method inside the acitivity with the TextViews that should be searched through. So I guess it's for activity, isn't it?

Comment: naah! its for fragment, let me update the code for activity... check the answer now

Comment: let me know if it works.. BTW i m sure it will work :)

Comment: This looks pretty good, thank you! Two more questions though, what do I have to put in line 4 instead of menu_search? ^^

Comment: Check updated answer now....create a menu file under the folder res > menu > menu_search.xml

Comment: SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)); This line is giving me a NullPointerExeption now, I feel like I have to learn a lot :D

Comment: Please check the menu_search.xml file is correctly under ,

res > menu > menu_search.xml.

you can check if its correctly placed or not by ctrl + click on that menu_search in line which it gives error.

Comment: Yes it is, there is also a file called options_menu.xml which I created yesterday similar to the menu_search.xml file. Is it possible that this is the problem? Do you need some kind of data, like the error code or something?

Comment: if both are similar files having similar ids, you can change id for one of the file. Or you can remove one file and use same file for all occurrences

Comment: Ok, that is not the problem. I will find a way to fix it later for sure, just another question real quick; in the public boolean onQueryTextSubmit method, what kind of operation do I put in there? Or do you know any keywords I can search for on the web? Thank you so much again!

Comment: in that operation part, if you have a list of content than by using loop you can compare the content with the content written in the searchview. **query** will return value in searchview and you can search from your existing bunch of data by that

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to do is search through text inside TextViews defined inside your layout. 
I am assuming here that the text source is a String Array/ArrayList (TextViewData) in a file "Data.java.

You can give this a try:

1) Make the activity/fragment `implement SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`

2) Create an empty ArrayList to store search entry results.

```
private ArrayList<Data> mSearchItems
```

3) Add this line to the code where you initialize your SearchView

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
```

4) Override the following methods:

i) Method called on submit:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    //Call a user defined mathod to handle the search.
    handleSearch(query, Data.TextViewData)
}
```

ii) Method called on changing the text in the search box

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    handleSearch(query, Data.TextViewData)
}
```

5)

```
private void handleSearch(String Query, ArrayList<Data> queryList){
mSearchItems.clear();
for(Data data  : queryList){
    if(data.textviewone.toLowerCase().contains(Query.toLowerCase()) ||
    data.textviewtwo.toLowerCase().contains(Query.toLowerCase()))
    mSearchItems.add(data);
    //You can then swap the recycler view (if being used) or hide other text views and display only the one being searched for (in case of a match)
   }
}
```

Comment: So I have to store my TextViews inside an ArrayList, right?

Comment: The "text" to be exact and not TextViews

Comment: Example:
If you have a TextView with id textviewone and ArrayList<String> textData.
And you wanna display "My name is userxyz" in the TextView. You can add the text to the list like:
 textData.add("My name is userxyz"); 
and display it inside the textView as: 

TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewone);
txt.setText(textData.get(0));

Comment: I see, and then the search will find the text inside the ArrayList and then show the TextView that is bound to the the searched text? Thank you btw!

Comment: You are welcome :).. If my answer helped, do give a thumbs up!