# Xamarin Android search Recycler View items

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement the SearchView from the support library. I want the user to be to use the SearchView to filter a List of books in a RecyclerView.

Comment: Can you share what you did so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview).

You just have to implement RecyclerView logic in [Custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) for SearchView.

Comment: But here used  androidStudio (java) and i need xamarin visual Studio (c#) and my doubt is too accurate, plz help