# Search View not Searching ListView

Tags: java, android

I am Trying to Display the Contact From Phone to the `ListView`(Which is used in a `Fragment`)..... I have Tried Putting a `SearchView` to Filter Data from `ListView`.....

**Search View Does Not Filter Data ....**

Pls Help ...I Am badly Stuck...

ScreenShot of App having `SearchView` over List View Showing Contact Details....

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8sFN35Zdhnfa0RtVEJKc2V2WG8/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8sFN35ZdhnfWTljaTRWaGY3c1E/view?usp=sharing

contactfragment.xml , GetContactAdapter.java , **Contact_Fragment3.java**

are three different files..

```
**contractfragment.xml**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/searchContactLIST"
        android:queryHint="Search...."
        android:clickable="true"
        >
    </SearchView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lists"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        />
</LinearLayout>





 **GetContactAdapter.java**

package com.example.cosmic.zumi_test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class GetContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {


    String[] phone = {};
    String[] names = {};
    int[] img = {};
    Context c;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public class Viewholder {
        TextView names;
        TextView address;
        ImageView img;
    }

    public GetContactAdapter(Context context, String[] names, String[] add) {

        super(context, R.layout.customcontactlist, names);

        this.c = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.phone = add;
        this.img = img;


    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customcontactlist, null);

        }
        Viewholder viewholder = new Viewholder();

        viewholder.names = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);

        viewholder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_no);


        viewholder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_contactlist);

//ASSIGN DATA
        viewholder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.com_facebook_button_icon_blue);
        viewholder.names.setText(names[position]);
        viewholder.address.setText(phone[position]);

        return convertView;

    }


}
**Contact_Fragment3.java**



 package com.example.cosmic.zumi_test;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.ContentResolver;
    import android.content.ContentUris;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
    import android.text.TextUtils;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Filterable;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by cosmic on 31/12/16.
     */
    public class Contact_FRAGMENT3 extends Fragment {


        private Uri uriContact;
        private String contactID;
        private ListView lstNames;
        private GetContactAdapter adapter;
        // Request code for READ_CONTACTS. It can be any number > 0.
        private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 100;

        private android.widget.SearchView search;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactfragment, container, false);

            this.lstNames = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lists);
            this.search = (android.widget.SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.searchContactLIST);


            // Read and show the contacts
            showContacts();


            return v;

        }


        private void showContacts() {
            // Check the SDK version and whether the permission is already granted or not.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
            } else {
                // Android version is lesser than 6.0 or the permission is already granted.


                List<String> contacts = getContactNames();
                //  String[] arr_contact=contacts.to
                List<String> contacts_no = getContactNo();


                String[] strarray = new String[contacts.size()];
                contacts.toArray(strarray);


                String[] strarray2 = new String[contacts_no.size()];
                contacts_no.toArray(strarray2);


                adapter = new GetContactAdapter(getContext(), strarray, strarray2);

                lstNames.setAdapter(adapter);


                search.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                        return true;

                    }
                });


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
            if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission is granted
                    showContacts();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Until you grant the permission, we cannot display the names", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }


        private List<String> getContactNames() {
            List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

            List<String> number = new ArrayList<>();
            // Get the ContentResolver
            ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            // Move the cursor to first. Also check whether the cursor is empty or not.
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                // Iterate through the cursor
                do {
                    // Get the contacts name
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String numbers = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    number.add(numbers);
                    contacts.add(name);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // Close the curosor
            cursor.close();

            return contacts;
        }


        private List<String> getContactNo() {

            List<String> number = new ArrayList<>();
            // Get the ContentResolver
            ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            // Get the Cursor of all the contacts
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            // Move the cursor to first. Also check whether the cursor is empty or not.
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                // Iterate through the cursor
                do {
                    // Get the contacts name
                    //  String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String numbers = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    number.add(numbers);
                    // contacts.add(name);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            // Close the curosor
            cursor.close();

            return number;

        }


    }
```

Comment: Didn't you get any error in GetContactAdapter ? Because you haven't overriden any methods from Filterable?

Comment: @Raghavendra Pls explain...

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

Answer (score 0):

try this code if it might help you

```
public class SearchViewFilterMode extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;

    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchview_filter);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain to the Author how it'll solve. Post some description along with code?

Comment: What is wrong in my Code...The Code List the Contact Very Well ...But Only Problem is Searching ...Pls Help

Comment: @siddhesh More Over Your List Does not Reset ...Removing all char from Search View..