# Speeding up AutoComplete algorithm with a big Array List

Tags: java, android, search, arraylist, autocomplete

I'm dealing with the **InstantSearch feature** on my Android App and the result I'd like to achieve is the one in the following picture.

[image: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439/4907138]

Everything works properly except for one thing. The ArrayList I'm using is BIG (it contains almost 400k words). Hence, I have performance issues while showing my results on the ListView (it lags a lot).

I'm pretty sure it's caused by the length of my Wordlist because, reducing its number of words, everything is smooth as butter.

Here's my filtering code in the **Adapter Class**:

```
private class SearchResultsFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        ArrayList<String> found = new ArrayList<>();
        if (constraint != null) {
            for (String word : MainActivity.WordList) {
                if (word.startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    found.add(word);
                }
            }
        }

        filteredList = found;
        filterResults.values = found;
        filterResults.count = found.size();

        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
        if (filterResults.count > 0) {
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "Results", "FOUND");
            results.clear();
            results.addAll((ArrayList<String>) filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "Results", "-");
            results.clear();
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }

    }
}
```

That's how I load my ArrayList in my **MainActivity**:

```
public static void loadDictionary(Activity activity) {
        //loading wordslist from file.
        BufferedReader line_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.wordlist)));
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = line_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                WordList.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Collections.sort(WordList);
```

Thank you everyone,

Have a nice day.

Comment: do not show  AutoComplete until someone types at least X letters ... play with X value to fit your needs

Comment: @Selvin Thank you for your answer. I don't think that this solution solves my issue, because my code still iterates through the whole list every time I type a letter. Instead, I'd like to know if I can use a different algorithm that reduces the amount of words to check each time. Perhaps it might be better use a different data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a collaborator in Cesarsk's project, I noticed that our problem was the **performFiltering** method. The Wordlist we used, had 394.000+ elements in it and the performFiltering method checked all of them each time the user typed a letter in the EditText of the SearchBar even if it should have excluded some on each iteration. So I implemented a simple way to split the list in different sublists. Each list contains only word starting with a single letter from the alphabet.

Meaning:

- List 1 contains only words starting with the letter "*a*"
- List 2 contains only words starting with the letter "*b*"

  And so on...

Then I put all the lists in an **HashMap** with *key = letter of the alphabet*. Doing this, now We are able to select only the sublist matching the first letter the user typed, and the loop checks a lot less words, generating results instantly.

Here's some code:

```
@Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

        ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> temp_list = null;
        ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> found = new ArrayList<>();

        if (constraint != null) {
            if (!(constraint.toString().isEmpty())) {
                temp_list = MainActivity.Wordlists_Map.get(constraint.toString().substring(0,1).toLowerCase());

                if(temp_list != null){
                    for(Pair<String, String> element : temp_list){
                        if(element.first.startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                            found.add(element);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        filterResults.values = found;
        filterResults.count = found.size();

        return filterResults;
    }
```