# Strange behavior for RecyclerView filtering

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439/2402265) instructions I've created RecyclerView filtering in my app. Almost everything works fine but there are 2 strange things.

When I input text into search view and there is only one item which meets requirements until I hide keyboard I can't see this item.

Second problem is more complicated because it occurs from time to time. My item in RecyclerView has an image in background and not always when filtering image is loaded properly.

Because I now my description might be unclear here is an gif which shows the problem:
[image: Gif with problem]

Here is my adapter class:

```
package com.ostojan.x360.view;

import android.support.v7.util.SortedList;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.ostojan.x360.R;
import com.ostojan.x360.model.Game;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class GameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameViewHolder> {

    private SortedList<Game> games;
    private ArrayList<Game> allGames;
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    public GameAdapter(View.OnClickListener onClickListener, List<Game> games) {
        this(onClickListener);
        this.games.addAll(games);
        this.allGames.addAll(games);
    }

    public GameAdapter(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
        this.games = new SortedList<Game>(Game.class, new GamesSortedListCallback(this));
        this.allGames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_game, parent, false);
        view.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return new GameViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(GameViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Game game = games.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(game.getTitle());
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(game.getCoverLink().toString())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_loading)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
                .into(holder.coverImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return games.size();
    }

    public void add(Game game) {
        this.games.add(game);
        this.allGames.add(game);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addAll(Collection<Game> games) {
        this.games.addAll(games);
        this.allGames.addAll(games);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void remove(Game game) {
        games.beginBatchedUpdates();
        games.remove(game);
        allGames.remove(game);
        games.endBatchedUpdates();
    }

    public void replaceAll(Collection<Game> games) {
        this.games.beginBatchedUpdates();
        List<Game> gamesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.games.size(); i++) {
            Game game = this.games.get(i);
            if (!games.contains(game)) {
                gamesToRemove.add(game);
            }
        }
        for (Game game : gamesToRemove) {
            this.games.remove(game);
        }
        this.games.addAll(games);
        this.games.endBatchedUpdates();
    }

    public Game get(int index) {
        return this.games.get(index);
    }

    public Collection<Game> getGames() {
        return allGames;
    }

    public void clear() {
        this.games.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void search(String query) {
        replaceAll(filterGames(query));
    }

    private Collection<Game> filterGames(String query) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        List<Game> filteredGames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Game game : allGames) {
            String gameTitle = game.getTitle().toLowerCase();
            if (gameTitle.contains(query)) {
                filteredGames.add(game);
            }
        }
        return filteredGames;
    }
}
```

View holder:

```
package com.ostojan.x360.view;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ostojan.x360.R;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.text_title)
    TextView title;
    @BindView(R.id.image_cover)
    ImageView coverImage;

    public GameViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

SortedList callback:

```
package com.ostojan.x360.view;

import android.support.v7.util.SortedList;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.ostojan.x360.model.Game;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class GamesSortedListCallback extends SortedList.Callback<Game> {
    private static final Comparator<Game> GAMES_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Game>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Game o1, Game o2) {
            return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
        }
    };
    private RecyclerView.Adapter<GameViewHolder> adapter;

    public GamesSortedListCallback(RecyclerView.Adapter<GameViewHolder> adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Game o1, Game o2) {
        return GAMES_COMPARATOR.compare(o1, o2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
        adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(Game oldItem, Game newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(Game item1, Game item2) {
        return item1.getId() == item1.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
        adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
        adapter.notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }
}
```

And here how I call filtering from activity:

```
RecyclerView gamesList;
GameAdapter gamesAdapter;

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    onQueryTextChange(query);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    gamesAdapter.search(newText);
    gamesList.scrollToPosition(0);
    return true;
}
```