# Searching Through RecyclerView - Xamarin.Droid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been searching for the Xamarin way of searching through a recyclerView. Can anyone kindly refer me to a demo on how to do that in the Xamarin way?

Comment: Here is a [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/) and [demo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/RecyclerViewer/) about how to use RecyclerView in Xamarin.Android.

Comment: @YorkShen  Not on how to use it but filter the recycler view using the search icon :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote up a simple demo about how to implement this feature, effect like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6SM.gif).
You can see it in this [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/aixiaozi/Xamarin.Android.Views/tree/master/RecyclerViewSearch).

For more information, you could read the document : [Filtering ListView with SearchView](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/15170/filtering-listview-with-searchview) in Xamarin.Android and [Xaver Kapeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview) about filter a `RecyclerView` with a `SearchView`.

Thanks for Xaver Kapeller's answer, his answer about Searching Through `RecyclerView` was great, so I decide translate it to Xamarin to help more people.

1. **Setting up the `SearchView`**

In the folder `res/menu` create a new file called `main.xml`. In it add an item and set the `actionViewClass` to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`. Since you are using the support library you have to use the namespace of the support library to set the `actionViewClass` attribute. Your xml file should look something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
     <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
           android:title="Search"
           android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
           app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
           app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
  </menu>
```

In your `Activity` you have to inflate this menu xml like usual, then you can look for the `MenuItem` which contains the `SearchView` and add a delegate on `QueryTextChange` which we are going to use to listen for changes to the text entered into the `SearchView`:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main, menu);

        var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.action_search);
        var searchView = MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);
        _searchView = searchView.JavaCast<Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView>();

        _searchView.QueryTextChange += (s, e) => _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);

        _searchView.QueryTextSubmit += (s, e) =>
        {
            // Handle enter/search button on keyboard here
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Searched for: " + e.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            e.Handled = true;
        };

        MenuItemCompat.SetOnActionExpandListener(item, new SearchViewExpandListener(_adapter));

        return true;
    }

    private class SearchViewExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListener
    {
        private readonly IFilterable _adapter;

        public SearchViewExpandListener(IFilterable adapter)
        {
            _adapter = adapter;
        }

        public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item)
        {
            _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter("");
            return true;
        }

        public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

2. **Setting up the `Adapter`**

First, add a model class that will be used for this sample :

```
public class Chemical
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DrawableId { get; set; }
}
```

It's just your basic model which will display a text in the `RecyclerView`. This is the layout that display the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="5dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chemImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chemName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chemImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is the `ViewHolder` for the `ChemicalHolder` class:

```
    public class ChemicalHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
        public TextView Caption { get; private set; }

        public ChemicalHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
        {
            Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.chemImage);
            Caption = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.chemName);
        }
    }
```

3. **Implementing the `RecyclerView.Adapter`**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, IFilterable
{
    private List<Chemical> _originalData;
    private List<Chemical> _items;
    private readonly Activity _context;

    public Filter Filter { get; private set; }

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Activity activity, IEnumerable<Chemical> chemicals)
    {
        _items = chemicals.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();
        _context = activity;

        Filter = new ChemicalFilter(this);
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Chemical, parent, false);
        ChemicalHolder vh = new ChemicalHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ChemicalHolder vh = holder as ChemicalHolder;

        var chemical = _items[position];

        vh.Image.SetImageResource(chemical.DrawableId);
        vh.Caption.Text = chemical.Name;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return _items.Count; }
    }

    public class ChemicalHolder{...

    private class ChemicalFilter{//Implement the Filter logic
 }
```

4. **Implementing the filter logic**

   ```
   private class ChemicalFilter : Filter
   {
       private readonly RecyclerViewAdapter _adapter;
       public ChemicalFilter(RecyclerViewAdapter adapter)
       {
           _adapter = adapter;
       }

       protected override FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)
       {
           var returnObj = new FilterResults();
           var results = new List<Chemical>();
           if (_adapter._originalData == null)
               _adapter._originalData = _adapter._items;

           if (constraint == null) return returnObj;

           if (_adapter._originalData != null && _adapter._originalData.Any())
           {
               // Compare constraint to all names lowercased. 
               // It they are contained they are added to results.
               results.AddRange(
                   _adapter._originalData.Where(
                       chemical => chemical.Name.ToLower().Contains(constraint.ToString())));
           }

           // Nasty piece of .NET to Java wrapping, be careful with this!
           returnObj.Values = FromArray(results.Select(r => r.ToJavaObject()).ToArray());
           returnObj.Count = results.Count;

           constraint.Dispose();

           return returnObj;
       }

       protected override void PublishResults(ICharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
       {
           using (var values = results.Values)
               _adapter._items = values.ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>()
                   .Select(r => r.ToNetObject<Chemical>()).ToList();

           _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

           // Don't do this and see GREF counts rising
           constraint.Dispose();
           results.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```
5. **Use it to implement this feature**

   ```
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
       SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

       var chemicals = new List<Chemical>
       {
           new Chemical {Name = "Niacin", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
           new Chemical {Name = "Biotin", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
           new Chemical {Name = "Chromichlorid", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
           new Chemical {Name = "Natriumselenit", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
           new Chemical {Name = "Manganosulfate", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
           new Chemical {Name = "Natriummolybdate", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
           new Chemical {Name = "Ergocalciferol", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
           new Chemical {Name = "Cyanocobalamin", DrawableId = Resource.Drawable.Icon},
       };

       _recyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);
       _adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,chemicals);
       _LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
       _recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(_LayoutManager);
       _recyclerView.SetAdapter(_adapter);//
   ```

Comment: in this line `_searchView.QueryTextChange += (s, e) => _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);` where do call `_adapter` from?

Comment: Initialize the `_adapter` in `OnCreate` method : `_adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,chemicals)`.

Comment: in this line `.Select(r => r.ToNetObject<Chemical>()).ToList();`, i get an error for `ToNetObject`. do i have to install any package for that?

Comment: this is the error reference when i try to build `/Users/emmnock/Documents/Projects/peaceApp/Droid/Recycler/PeaceHeroHolder.cs(40,40): Error CS1061: 'Object' does not contain a definition for 'ToNetObject' and no extension method 'ToNetObject' accepting a first argument of type 'Object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (App.Droid)`

Comment: @Switz, please add this class [ObjectExtensions](https://github.com/aixiaozi/Xamarin.Android.Views/blob/master/RecyclerViewSearch/ObjectExtensions.cs).