# xamarin android listview filter using searchview or edittext

Tags: android, xamarin

I've used many examples for implementing search in listview but none of them work. I have a listview binding from a JSON array, I want to implement a simple way to search items in a listview. I found some examples on the internet but they doesn't work.
I am using Xamarin Android.

mainActivity:

```
   DaftarGaleri = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.dataList);
        itemGaleri = new List<Galeri>();
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(BaseUri);
        progress = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);

        //Showing loading progressbar
        progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted;

    }

    private void WebClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            itemGaleri = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Galeri>>(e.Result);
            CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, itemGaleri);
            DaftarGaleri.Adapter = adapter;
            progress.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            DaftarGaleri.ItemClick += DaftarGaleri_ItemClick;

        }
        );

    }
```

customlistadapter class:

```
  public class CustomListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Galeri>
{
    public CustomListAdapter()
    {
    }
    Activity context;
    List<Galeri> list;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity _context, List<Galeri> _list) : base()
    {
        this.context = _context;
        this.list = _list;
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return list.Count; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Galeri this[int index]
    {
        get { return list[index]; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;

        // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        // otherwise create a new one
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.item, parent, false);


        Galeri item = this[position];
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.productname).Text = item.meta_title;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.category).Text = item.model;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.description).Text = item.description;

        using (var imageView = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.Photo))
        {
            string url = Android.Text.Html.FromHtml("http://www.termamed.com/store/image/"+item.image).ToString();

            //Download and display image
            Koush.UrlImageViewHelper.SetUrlDrawable(imageView,url, Resource.Drawable.products);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

can anyone help.. thanks

Comment: Would you describe the errors you are getting?

Comment: you absolutely have to tell which examples you tried because people here will waste their time writing answers suggesting what you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> xamarin android listview filter using searchview or edittext

You could refer to [Cheesebaron's SearchView-Sample](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SearchView-Sample): showing how to `Filter` `ListView`'s using `SearchView` and custom `Filter` implementation.

And don't forget to add the [ObjectExtensions](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/SearchView-Sample/blob/master/SearchViewSample/ObjectExtensions.cs) class in your project.

---

Some other useful link:

- [Searching Through RecyclerView - Xamarin.Droid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44998483/searching-through-recyclerview-xamarin-droid/45011379#45011379)
- [Filterable adapter with custom object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071186/filterable-adapter-with-custom-object/47089505#47089505)