# Filter recycler list

Tags: android, filter

When i search for first time list shows correct data but second time if i search same keyword again it duplicates list.Previous entries are not deleted.
    I tried to clear filter_list but it doesnot load data second time on list and if i add announcements in filter list in constructor it doesnot add items in filter list. How to resolve this issue??

```
public void filter(String charText) {

    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    filter_list.addAll(announcement);
    announcement.clear();

    if (charText.length() == 0) {

        announcement.addAll(filter_list);

    } else {

        for (GT gt : filter_list) {

            if (gt.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {

                announcement.add(gt);

            }

        }

    }

notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: can you post your filter code here

Comment: you can clear temp list after selecting or item click

Comment: Are you clearing `filter_list` at all? It looks like each time through, `announcements` is added to `filter_list` and then added again in the for loop.

Comment: check out this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview) it explains how to filter data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First copy your list to temp list in you adapter

```
sampleListTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
sampleListTemp = sampleList;
```

Now implement this function in adapter and call with string whcich you want to filter

```
public void setFilter(String str) {
        sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (eventsListTemp.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < eventsListTemp.size(); i++) {
                if (sampleListTemp.get(i).contains(str.toLowerCase())) {

                    sampleList.add(sampleListTemp.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and when you want full list than just pass blank str.