# Can the android.support.v7.util.sortedlist be implemented in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library

I was recently looking through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview?rq=1) Question and one of the answers provided uses the v7 Support library Sorted List and SortedList.Callback.

How would this be used with Xamarin.Android, particularly with RecyclerView?

Also, what is the purpose of SortedList.BatchedCallback

Resources:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.Callback.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/SortedList.BatchedCallback.html

Sample in Java:
https://github.com/Wrdlbrnft/Searchable-RecyclerView-Demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Android.Support.V7.UtilSortedList` is included in the Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView NuGet package (at least as of v25.3.1), if you can use RecyclerView you can use SortedList.

As the documentation describes in the link you posted, `BatchedCallback` is intended as a performance optimization to avoid bombarding the RecyclerView with many list operations that can be batched into a single operation.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example?

Comment: Of what? The link in your question provides a thorough example. Is there something in particular you're having trouble translating into Xamarin?

Comment: The question is how to implement the Sorted List and Callback in C# for Xamarin. The link provided is an example in Java.

Comment: I don't have time to translate the entire sample project, sorry. The C# code will be substantially similar to the Java, modulo Xamarin's naming conventions (CamelCasing, properties in place of get/set methods, etc).