# How to add Search view for Firebase realtime database?

Tags: android-layout, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an android app with Firebase real-time database. I created `RecyclerView` with `Cardview` and want to make a `SearchView` in the toolbar for all the data. Please help me how to create this.

It is my Adapter file

```
public class RecycleAdepter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdepter.MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Blog> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
RecycleAdepter(ArrayList<Blog> arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList=arrayList;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bank_row,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.Title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView Title;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Title=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Idiom_title);
    }
}
public void setFilter(ArrayList<Blog> newList)
{
```

This is my Search code for Main activity

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchbar);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Can you specify please xml or java file?

Comment: You should post the Minimal, Verifiable and complete code that shows what you've tried. More details can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank u all for your quick support. I am new here. Below 5 reputation I can't upload any image . Other side when I am trying to paste the code it shows sone error.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have already downloaded all the data in a `RecyclerView` and then you just implement `SearchView` and search the data downloaded within the `RecyclerView`. This has already been explained here: [How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)