# Android RecyclerView Adapter - Hiding/filter out items by viewholder type

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have an adapter with 3 `ViewHolder` types.

```
private static final int TYPE_M = 0;
private static final int TYPE_H = 1;
private static final int TYPE_T= 2;
```

I want to to able to filter items in the `RecyclerView` by the view holder type. Any standard way of doing this or do I have to use something like a loop and make items invisible that way?

Item view type selection :

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    MyItem myItem = listitems.get(position);
    if (myItem.getType() == "M"){
        return TYPE_M;
    }
    else if (myItem.getType() == "H"){
        return TYPE_H;
    }
    else if (myItem.getType() == "T"){
        return TYPE_T;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30429439/2949834

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this where displayList is filtered list to be displayed and dataList consists of all the elements.

```
public void filterList(int viewType) {
    displayList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
        if (getItemViewType(i) == viewType){
            displayList.add(dataList.get(i));
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```