# Searchable Recycleview in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, searchview, android-search

I have a `MainActivity` that shows a `Fragment` containing a `RecyclerView`.
I am loading data from SQL using an `Asynctask`, all the data shows perfectly.

What I want to know is, I've got a search icon in my toolbar inflated in the `MainActivity`, when the user clicks on it and enters data, it should filter through the `RecyclerView` in the `Fragment`.

I have already implemented `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` in the `MainActivity`, I've also implemented methods `onQueryTextChange()` and `onQueryTextSubmit()`. I just don't know how to filter the `RecyclerView` in the `Fragment` directly using the search in the `MainActivity`.

Comment: Once the results are filtered you need to update the adapter list and call `notifyDatasetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your `Adapter Class` and implement it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562572/7822626)

To get your Recyclerview's Adapter reference in `MainActivity` or `Host Activity` you can ( but not recommended ) do like this:

```
RecyclerView recylerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
MyAdapter myAdapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
```

Then in your `onQueryTextChange()` and `onQueryTextSubmit()` method do :

```
myAdapter.filter(queryText);
```

Comment: what is an item referring to?

Comment: Your `List<Type>` element.

Comment: can you please take a look at my question, I dont have one item

Comment: I will give you plenty of points strarting from this +1

Comment: Yes, please point me to it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958847/null-object-reference-in-recycleview

Comment: cannot comment in your thread due to less than  50 reputation. Are you using ButterKnife to inject recyclerview?

Comment: its okay comment here,no i dont use butterKnife

Comment: can you show me where you're initialising recyclerview?