# search in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

i have a fragment that have a recyclerview i'm trying to use setOnQueryTextListener to search some specific data and display the new data instead of the old one

this is my Fragmenttask.kt file

[image]

```
class Fragmenttask : Fragment(), SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null
    private var mSwipeRefreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        //container!!.removeAllViews()
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        val CustumViewtask = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragmenttask, container, false)
        val taskMainRV = CustumViewtask.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_main) as RecyclerView
        //taskMainRV.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)

        taskMainRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        //recyclerView_main.adapter = MainAdapter()

        fetchJson(taskMainRV)

        return CustumViewtask
    }

    override fun onRefresh() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "تم التحميل بنجاح والحمد لله", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_user, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem) as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "أكتب كلمة بحث ..."

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextChange(q: String): Boolean {
                println("my serch : $q")
                //fetchJson(taskMainRV)
                //adaptertask?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                //notifyDataSetChanged
                println("mohamed 78797987897987987987987987987987987987897")
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(q: String): Boolean {
                println("my serch : $q")

                println("mohamed 78797987897987987987987987987987987987897**************")
                return false
            }
        })
        //searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
    }

    fun onQueryTextChange(query: String): Boolean {
        // Here is where we are going to implement the filter logic
        return false
    }

    fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    fun fetchJson(RSV: RecyclerView) {

        //SharedPreferences
        val MY_APP_INFO: String = "UserInfo"
        val prefs = activity.getSharedPreferences(MY_APP_INFO, AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val LoggedUserId = prefs.getString("UserId", null)
        var serchqury = arguments.getString("serchqury")

        if(serchqury.isNullOrEmpty()){
            serchqury = ""
        }
        println(serchqury+" ------------**/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/ ")
        println("your code is : $LoggedUserId")

        println("Attempting to Fetch JSON")

        val url = "http://www.deraah-rs.com/1mahamatonline/html/Restful/get_tasks.php"

        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val formBody = FormBody.Builder().add("UserId", LoggedUserId)
                                                    .add("serchqury", serchqury).build()

        val request = Request.Builder().url(url)
                .post(formBody)
                .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                val body = response?.body()?.string()
                println("mohamed : $body")

                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val tasksfeed = gson.fromJson(body, M_tasksFeed::class.java)

                activity.runOnUiThread {
                    RSV.adapter = MainAdaptertasks(tasksfeed)
                    if(taskfragmentprogressbar != null){
                        taskfragmentprogressbar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    }
                    //ChatAdapter(Context, tasksfeed)
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Failed to execute request")
            }
        })
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener!!.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
        }
    }



    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): Fragmenttask {
            val fragment = Fragmenttask()
            val args = Bundle()
            fragment.arguments = args
            return fragment
        }
    }
}// Required empty public constructor
```

......................................................................................................................................

Comment: Your code is quite unreadable . Here is two things you can do if search is performing locally on data then you should use [Filterable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable). And if you have to hit a service on text change for search then use a `Handler` with some seconds delay to hit API . Or you can use `debounce` operator if you are using `RX`.

Comment: *to search some specific data and display the new data instead of the old one*. Be more specific/

Comment: You can set adapter with new data (as per the search keyword) inside onQueryTextChange().
If keyword is empty, set original data