# How to compare the content of a TableRow (of a code-generated) Table with a String?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i've been trying to do that and it basically says that the "content" that i'm trying to get is null.
This is the code that i'm testing (the commented part is the actual code that i'm trying to get it to work i just added the println to see if the data that was getting was right, which it wasn't)

```
public void FiltarBusqueda(String filtro) {
    int count=0;
    for (int r = 0; r < mTableLayout.getChildCount(); r++) {
        TableRow trow = (TableRow) mTableLayout.getChildAt(r);
        for(int c=0;c <= trow.getChildCount();c++){
            System.out.println(""+trow.getChildAt(c));
            /*if (trow.getChildAt(c).toString() != filtro) {
                count++; }
            if(count==3){
                mTableLayout.removeView(trow); }*/
            }
    }
}

public void onClickFiltro(View v){
    EditText filtro = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtproducto);
    FiltarBusqueda(filtro.getText().toString());
}
```

*Also the thing that creates the tablerows for each is in the same class
*LinearLayout Thing:

```
final LinearLayout layCustomer = new LinearLayout(this);
            layCustomer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layCustomer.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);
            layCustomer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));

            final TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
            if (i == -1) {
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv3.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 5);
                tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
            } else {
                tv3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                tv3.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 5);
                tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
            }

            tv3.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);


            if (i == -1) {
                tv3.setText("Productos");
                tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f0f0f0"));
            } else {
                tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f8f8f8"));
                tv3.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                tv3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, smallTextSize);
                tv3.setText(row.productName);
            }
            layCustomer.addView(tv3);
```

Comment: What are the children of the TableRow?

Comment: Well, the cells i guess

Comment: But what are the cells? What are you trying to compare to a String, and what is that String?

Comment: Basically, the entire table adds products from a JSON, so the String that's entering as "filtro" is the word that comes from an editText, and it's the word that needs to be compared to each row, meaning, it needs to search the product with the String that's entering

Comment: So are the cells TextViews then?

Comment: Yes, Precisely1

Comment: So you want to remove that row if none of its cells contain the filter String?

Comment: Yes, but what i'm really tying to do is getting the actual data from each cell individually so i can compare it in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView#toString()` doesn't get the text inside that TextView. It just prints the classname and instance hashcode. You need to use `TextView#getText()#toString()`.

Use this:

```
public void FiltarBusqueda(String filtro) {
    for (int r = 0; r < mTableLayout.getChildCount(); r++) {
        TableRow trow = (TableRow) mTableLayout.getChildAt(r);

        boolean hasMatch = false;

        for (int c = 0; c <= trow.getChildCount(); c++) {
            String text = ((TextView) trow.getChildAt(c)).getText().toString();

            hasMatch = text.equals(filtro); //when comparing Strings, use `equals()` not `==`
            if (hasMatch) break;
        }

        if (!hasMatch) {
            mTableLayout.removeRow(trow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked with one of my tables, but maybe you can help me, the other one is actually filled with LinearLayouts, and then those are added to a table Row, and those are added to the Table Layout, and when i try to run it with this same code it says "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView"

Comment: What do the LinearLayouts contain?

Comment: They contain a TextView, check the edited question to kind of see how one of them works

Comment: I don't understand how your code is structured. You really should consider using a RecyclerView combined with a SearchView https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview

Comment: After what i edited, i create a TableRow named tr, and just go tr.addView(layCustomer), and finally add it to the table layout by adding mTableLayout.addView(tr)