# Adding Search function to Recycler view

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have tried many ways to implement search function into recyclerview. But the search function is not working.

XML

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/homeback"
    tools:context=".Churchcontact">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/churchcontacthead"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CHURCH CONTACT"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:fontFamily="@font/averia_gruesa_libre"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recylcerView2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Churchcontact.java

```java
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Churchcontact extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "http://droidparkz.in/parethumukal/churchcontact/churchapi.php";

    //a list to store all the products
    List<Churchcontactclass> churchcontactList;
    EditText editTextSearch;
    Churchcontactadapter adapter;
    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_churchcontact);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView2);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.churchcontactsearch);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.toolbar_menu);
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_search) {

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    //initializing the productlist
        churchcontactList = new ArrayList<>();
        //this method will fetch and parse json
        //to display it in recyclerview
        loadProducts();
    }

    private void loadProducts() {

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                churchcontactList.add(new Churchcontactclass(
                                        product.getInt("Id"),
                                        product.getString("Name"),
                                        product.getString("Housename"),
                                        product.getString("Bloodgroup"),
                                        product.getString("Phone")
                                ));
                            }

                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            Churchcontactadapter adapter = new Churchcontactadapter(Churchcontact.this, churchcontactList);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed () {
        super.onBackPressed();
        Intent i = new Intent(Churchcontact.this, Directory.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Churchcontactadapter.java

```java
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Churchcontactadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Churchcontactadapter.ProductViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private Context mCtx;
    private List<Churchcontactclass> churchcontactList;
    private List<Churchcontactclass> contactList;

    public Churchcontactadapter(Context mCtx, List<Churchcontactclass> churchcontactList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.churchcontactList = churchcontactList;
        this.contactList = new ArrayList<>(churchcontactList);

    }

    @Override
    public Churchcontactadapter.ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.churchcontact_list, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Churchcontactadapter.ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Churchcontactclass product = contactList.get(position);

        //loading the image

        holder.textViewName.setText(product.getName());
        holder.textViewHousename.setText(product.getHousename());
        holder.textViewBloodgroup.setText(product.getBloodgroup());
        holder.textViewPhone.setText(String.valueOf(product.getPhone()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactList.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }

    private Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Churchcontactclass> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(contactList);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Churchcontactclass item : contactList) {
                    if ((item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) || item.getBloodgroup().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            churchcontactList.clear();
            churchcontactList.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        TextView textViewName, textViewHousename, textViewBloodgroup, textViewPhone;
        ImageButton callnow;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewname2);
            textViewHousename = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewhousename2);
            textViewBloodgroup = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textbloodgroup2);
            textViewPhone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textphone2);

            callnow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.callnowbutton2);
            callnow.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (view == callnow) {

                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                String phoneno= textViewPhone.getText().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneno ));
                context.startActivity(call);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Churchcontactclass.java

```java
public class Churchcontactclass  {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String housename;
    private String bloodgroup;
    private String phone;

    public Churchcontactclass(int id, String name, String housename,String bloodgroup, String phone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.housename = housename;
        this.bloodgroup = bloodgroup;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getHousename() {
        return housename;
    }

    public String getBloodgroup() {
        return bloodgroup;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

}
```

I have tried several other codes too. But all of them were not working.

I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

A walkthrough is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview).
For your understandability, adding code for getFilter(). Please comment any further issues

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                contactList = churchcontactList;
            } else {

                ArrayList<Churchcontactclass> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (Churchcontactclass item : churchcontactList) {

                    if ((item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) || item.getBloodgroup().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
                }

                contactList = filteredList;
            }

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = contactList;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            contactList = (ArrayList<Churchcontactclass>) filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I have tried but showing error on " ItemExampleBinding ".. I dont understand what is the error