# Android recyclerview search filter not working

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Updating data but not changing. What would be the reason?  I tried a lot of methods, but none of them worked. No matter what I write, the result doesn't change. The list is still the same. Where am I doing wrong? I'm sure the adapter has been updated. Because I checked it. The problem must be something else.

[image: searchFilter]

**MainActivity**

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search Customer");
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
 PlaylistAdapter(Context c,List<M3UItem> list) {
        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.mItem = list;
        this.list = list;
}

 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    list = mItem;
                } else {
                    List<M3UItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (M3UItem row : filteredList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ) {
                            filteredList.add(row);

                        }
                    }

                    list = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = list;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                list = (ArrayList<M3UItem>) filterResults.values;

              notifyDataSetChanged();
                // refresh the list with filtered data

            }
        };
    }
```

**EDİT:**

**onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        final M3UItem item = mItem.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            holder.update(item);
        }
    }
```

**İtemHolder Update**

```
void update(M3UItem item) {


        try {
            name.setText(item.getItemName());
            int color = generator.getRandomColor();
            if (item.getItemIcon().isEmpty()) {
                textDrawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                        .buildRoundRect(String.valueOf(item.getItemName().charAt(0)), color, 100);
                cImg.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);
            } else {
                if (Utils.getInstance().isNetworkAvailable(mContext)) {
                    Glide.with(mContext).load(item.getItemIcon()).into(cImg);
                } else {
                    textDrawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                            .buildRoundRect(String.valueOf(item.getItemName().charAt(0)), color, 100);
                    cImg.setImageDrawable(textDrawable);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

    }
```

**MainActivity load item:**

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try { //new FileInputStream (new File(name)

            is = new FileInputStream(new File(strings[0])); // if u r trying to open file from asstes InputStream is = getassets.open(); InputStream
            final M3UPlaylist playlist = parser.parseFile(is);


            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    // Stuff that updates the UI
                    mAdapter.update(playlist.getPlaylistItems());
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });


            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Google2", "_loadFile: " + e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please send onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) and getItemCount() method of the Adapter.

Comment: please check edit.

Comment: Could be answered already by this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview/53134136

Comment: I already used it, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your onBindViewHolder and getItemCount try this changes in your Adapter class

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        final M3UItem item = list.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            holder.update(item);
        }
    }

@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
```

you also need to change your filter code and revised it like this

```
List<M3UItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (M3UItem row : mItem) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ) {
                            filteredList.add(row);

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: But my real list is "mItem."

Comment: Your RecyclerView does not change its items or does not show anything at all?

Comment: RecyclerView does not change its items

Comment: mItem indeed is your real list but we need to filter some items and then show these filtered items inside Recycler, we must use another list which represents these filtered items and I think that's where this.list come to play.

Comment: I try but again not working. İtems is not loadingn and recyclerveiw null.

Comment: what you mean  İtems is not loadingn and recyclerveiw null, do mean Recycler does not show anything?

Comment: please revise your filter code as I said in my answer and try again.

Comment: i've updated my answer about 40 min ago. please see it again. I think we are very close to solving this problem.

Comment: I still can't figure it out. I'm about to go nuts.

Comment: What is happening? Items do not change or no item at all?

Comment: No item at all.

Comment: Do you see items before searching?