# Manage how views are recycled in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm looking for a way to filter my data in a RecyclerView without the state of a given view affects another view when filter is applied. Pratically, I have this problem :
1. I add "Martins" to my friend list by clicking on the add button (image msSxq.png)
list without filter
[image]

2. I perform a search and I get this (image FGSwF.png):
   list after performing searching action
   [image]

It'is then clear that, as the seraching action is done, my list content change and then the new items take old items place and take old items button state !

I'm looking for a way to avoid this. I tried to read several post on similar subject but nothing (Example of link : [How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview))

Thank you for your helps !

Edit : 07/02/2020 - onBindViewHolder and Filtering Code

**onBindViewHolder (in my Custom Adapter)**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final FriendAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String mUsernameString = suggestionList.get(position);
    String mModUsernameString = suggestionList.get(position) + "_@chatter";

    holder.username.setText(mUsernameString);
    holder.mod_username.setText(mModUsernameString);

}
```

**Filtering methods (always in my Adapter)**

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return friendFilter;
}

private Filter friendFilter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        ArrayList<String> listFiltered = new ArrayList<>();

        if (fullSuggestionList != null) {
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                listFiltered.addAll(fullSuggestionList);
            } else {
                String searchTextLowerCase = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                for (String item : fullSuggestionList) {
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(searchTextLowerCase)) {
                        listFiltered.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = listFiltered;

            return results;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        if(results.values != null) {
            suggestionList.clear();
            suggestionList.addAll((ArrayList<String>) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};
```

**And finally, in my Activity where I perform searching action**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (adapter.getCompleteItemList() != null) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your code from `OnBindViewHolder`and your searching code

Comment: @COYG I've just updated the post !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I tried to understand deeply how recyclerview works and I found a solution that works perfectly. In fact, when we're filtering data in a searchview linked to a recyclerview, the last one, when it's not neccessary, recycles already created view and change simply its content. To avoid that, we have to create a unique identifier for each view created and tell to our recyclerview have unique view Ids. Pratically, I did those things :

In my data model, I create a method that generate a unique Id for each instance created a little bite like this :

```
public class MyDataModel {
    private long mId;
    ...//others variables here

    private long computeId(.../*some parameters if needed*/) {
        // write code here to generate your unique code
        return result;
    }

    public long getmId() {
        return this.mId;
    }
```

In my Adapter, then, I override the getItemId() method

```
@override public long getItemId(int position) {
    return myDataList.get(position).getmId();
}
```

And, always in my Adapter, in its constructor I add this line of code :

```
this.setHasStableIds(true);
```

That's all !