# How to filter RecyclerView with ArrayList by spinner item position, Android, java?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, spinner

I have `RecyclerView` and `Spinner`. `RecyclerView` contains `ArrayList<Note>`, a Note has fields "String title" and "int status", and the spinner has some positions. If I choose for example 1st position from `Spinner`, my `RecyclerView` has to show only Notes with status = 1

Comment: show your code (spinner selection part and your Model and adapter part)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer on another question which may be the possible duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37562572/12565133