# how to call recyclerview when user typing on editText in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, filter, android-edittext

I create a editText filter search. I want the recyclerView will show when user typing. In my apps, when user typing the filter was show, but the list recyclerView show too. maybe this video can explain what i mean [filterSearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwP8c.gif)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter a RecyclerView with a SearchView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code which works

**ADAPTER**

```
    class SearchAdapter(val context: Context, val item:List<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ChildHolder>() {
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ChildHolder {
            val inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.search_container,parent,false)
            return ChildHolder(inflator)
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
           return item.size
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ChildHolder, position: Int) {
            val current = item[position]
            holder.item.name.setText(current.name)
        }
    
        class ChildHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
            val item = view.country_container
        }
    }
    
    
    data class Item(val name:String)
```

**MAINACTIVITY**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var item:ArrayList<Item> = ArrayList()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        item.add(
            Item("russia")
        )
        item.add(
            Item("india")
        )
        item.add(
            Item("usa")
        )
        item.add(
            Item("china")
        )
        item.add(
            Item("uk")
        )
        item.add(
            Item("brazil")
        )
        item.add(
            Item("pakistan")
        )
        item.add(
            Item("sri lanka")
        )
        search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                val filtered = item.filter { item ->
                  item.name.contains(newText.toString())
                }
                constructRecycleView(filtered)
                return true
            }
        })
    }

    private fun constructRecycleView(item:List<Item>){
        val adapter = SearchAdapter(this,item)
        recycle_view.adapter = adapter
        recycle_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)
    }
}
```

**constructRecycleView** method always create's new adapter, you can also create methods where you can mutate the adapter item and call **notifyDatasetChanged** Method ,and please implement **onQueryTextSubmit**
on your own if not your application gives Error

```
 kotlin.NotImplementedError: An operation is not implemented: Not yet implemented
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

[image]