# How to implement Searchview in BottomSheetDialogFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

I wanted to implement searchview inside bottomsheetdialog fragment but i don't know how. I have this full screen bottom sheet dialog layout with a SearchView and Recyclerview in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_green"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_institution_name"
        style="@style/bo_texto_regular"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.01"
        android:text="Nome"
        android:textColor="#757575"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/tv_institution_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_institution_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_institution_name"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/magnifying_glass" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#ececec"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/searchView"
        tools:listitem="@layout/search_item_list" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my full screen BottomSheetDialogFragment :

```
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.WindowManager
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialog
import com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDialogFragment
import org.koin.android.ext.android.inject


class SearchDialog() : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
        dialog.setOnShowListener {

            val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
            val parentLayout =
                bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
            parentLayout?.let { it ->
                val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(it)
                setupFullHeight(it)
                behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            }
        }
        return dialog
    }

    private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
        val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
    }


    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_search, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

  
}
```

I wanted to make the data come from an array and that i could search it using searchview

My adapter :

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Filter
import android.widget.Filterable
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class SearchAdapter(private val list: List<InstitutionModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchViewHolder>() , Filterable{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SearchViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return SearchViewHolder(inflater, parent)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val dialogData: InstitutionModel = list[position]
        holder.bind(dialogData)
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

And this is the setOnQueryListener:

```
  searchViewInstitutions.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
//                searchView.clearFocus()
//                if (data.toString().contains(query)) {
//                    mAdapter.filter.filter(query)
//                }
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
                mAdapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return false
            }

        })

    }
```

Comment: So, what is the problem in using the searchView?

Comment: I tried doing searchView.setOnQueryTextListener but i couldn't filter the results from the adapter i created

Comment: I already have the model, viewholder and the adapter. I just want to use the setOnQueryTextListener to filter the results.

Comment: Can you share the adapter and the `searchView.setOnQueryTextListener`

Comment: I added to the description

Comment: This is normal as `getFilter()` didn't implemented yet

Comment: How do i implement it?

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview