# Recycler View not loading data when retrieved from cloud firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, my adapter class works when the data is added to myModel objects from an array of string resources and floats, but not when these strings are retrieved from firestore. I have done this with textViews in other parts of my application fine. At first I tried using `toObject<Model>()` to populate the list passed to my adapter and now I have manually got the data from the hashMap. I have used snackbars to ensure the data is in the list that is passed to my adapter. I have tried overriding the `onStart()` and `onstop()` to listen for changes to the database but `mAdapter` is a local variable in `oncreate()` and it is not important that the data in this recycler view updates in realtime, updating when the activity launches is plenty.

**This doesn't work:**

```
collection.get().addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
        for (i in 0 until querySnapshot.size()){

            val data = querySnapshot.documents[i].data
            val Model = Model()

            val name = data!!["Name"].toString()
            val rating = data!!["Rating"].toString().toFloat()
            Model.Name= name
            Model.Rating = rating




            list.add(Model)
```

**This does:**

```
    val myImageNameList = arrayOf(R.string.1, R.string.2, R.string.cafe_3, R.string.4, R.string.5, R.string.6, R.string.7, R.8)
    val myImageRatingList = arrayOf(2.4f, 4.1f, 3.6f, 3.4f, 2.8f, 1.9f, 4.1f, 3.9f )

    for (i in 0..7){
        val model = Model()
        model.Name = getString(myImageNameList[i])
        model.Rating = myImageRatingList[i]
        list.add(model)
    }
```

**Adapter class excerpt:**

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Adapter.ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false)

    return ViewHolder(v)
}

//bind the data to child views of the ViewHolder
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Adapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val info = imageModelArrayList[position]

    
    holder.txtMsg.text = info.Name
    holder.ratingbar.rating = info.Rating
    holder.ratingDecimal.text = "("+ info.Rating + ")"
}

//get the max size of the recycler view
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return imageModelArrayList.size
}

inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener{
    var txtMsg = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.firstLine) as TextView
    var ratingbar = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.rating) as RatingBar
```

I am confused why the second way of creating model objects works but the first does not, as far as I know in both instances I am creating a model object and assigning its fields with a  string and afloat, just in the first example the string and float happen to have come from the firestorm.

**edit**

the list is passed when instantiating myAdapter as param imageModelArrayList

```
      val recyclerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.recycler_view) as RecyclerView
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager


    val imageModelArrayList = populateList()
    val mAdapter = Adapter(imageModelArrayList)
    recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
```

Comment: In your first code snippet, how do you use the created `list`. Can you add that code in the question as well?

Comment: @ArpitShukla list is passed to myAdapter as param ImageModelArrayList edited question to clarify

Comment: Are `list` (in list.add(Model)) and `imageModelArrayList` same?

Comment: @ArpitShukla yes they are

Comment: You need to update your recycler view when you receive response from firestore i.e. inside addOnSuccessListener. Does your `populateList` function have anything other than what you pasted in the 1st snippet?

Comment: @ArpitShukla populate list only contains the first snippet, plus a few val declarations for list, db, mainView and collection. it then returns the list

Comment: Passing the recyclerView as a param into populate list and creating the adapter there worked, thankyou

Comment: Yeah, that's one way.

Comment: @ArpitShukla is there a better way? I'm having trouble using the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398247/how-to-filter-a-recyclerview-with-a-searchview to search through my list using a custom app bar using this method

Comment: What trouble are you having? Can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Passed the recyclerView into the method where my data is gathered, and created the adapter inside my addOnSuccessListener

```
 val data = querySnapshot.documents[i]
            val model = Model()

            val name = data!!["Name"].toString()
            val rating = data!!["Rating"].toString().toFloat()
            model.Name= name
            model.Rating = rating


            
            list.add(model)
            


        }
  
        val mAdapter = Adapter(list)
        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
    }
```